# Git push requires username and password

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-clone, git-pull

I cloned a Git repository from my GitHub account to my PC.

I want to work with both my PC and laptop, but with one GitHub account.

When I try to push to or pull from GitHub using my PC, it requires a username and password, but not when I'm using the laptop!

I don't want to type my username and password every time I interact with `origin`. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to register the pubkey with your Github account (https://github.com/account/ssh) and configure your SSH client to use the right username.

Comment: I have done all of that but still it requires username and password! is it possible to use one account with two PCs?

Comment: This question covers all your options for this quite well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github

Comment: No need to switch over to ssh anymore. It's possible with HTTPS too. Check my answer.

Comment: I prefer using an [encrypted netrc.gpg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309) in which I can store all my credentials for https remote repo. And that works well with the new [GitHub two-factor authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309)!

Comment: I dont know how often I ended up in this thread because I took the https url instead of the ssh...

Comment: Note for those using two factor authorization: you will need to use an access token instead of your password. See [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to cache https credentials for pushing commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-cache-https-credentials-for-pushing-commits)

Comment: You can also consider [this cross-site Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26371/ssh-prompts-for-password-despite-ssh-authorized-keys#comment35605_26371) or [SSH Key - Still asking for password and passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21095054/4575793) (possible duplicate)

Answer (score 2520, accepted):

A common cause is cloning using the default (HTTPS) instead of SSH. You can correct this by going to your repository, clicking "Clone or download", then clicking the "Use SSH" button above the URL field and updating the URL of your origin remote like this:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

You can check if you have added the remote as HTTPS or SSH using:

```
git remote -v
```

This is documented at GitHub: [Switching remote URLs from HTTPS to SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh).

Comment: Then as I said, your ssh keys never come into play.  If you want to use ssh, you need to use the ssh clone url instead

Comment: And to figure out how to change the URL, go here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2432799/60488 (spoiler: `git remote set-url origin git://new.url.here`)

Comment: You can check your remotes with the command: git remote -v  and then if it's not correct, you can use: git remote rm aliasname  (like "origin" for ex.) and re-add using: git remote add git@github.com:xxxxx again like mentioned here, the https style remote will not use your SSH keys.

Comment: another way to change this is to edit the `.git/config` in your repo. edit the url under `[remote "origin"]` to use the `git://` url instead of `https://`. Thanks @Tekkub

Comment: This worked for me, having teh same username/password prompting problem. Note that "username" is your github username and "repo.git" is the name of your repo (I did not include the ".git" on the end, and that still worked for me). The remainder was entered verbatim.

Comment: Issuing `git remote -v` with the same issue returned `origin https://github.com/myusername/my-repo-name.git` After fixing the problem it returns `origin git@github.com:myusername/my-repo-name` (both for fetch and push). Hopefully that will be useful in trying to understand the difference.

Comment: If you can't user ssh for security restrictions (like me) you can do:`git remote set-url origin https://name:password@github.com/repo.git` [(extracted from a comment here)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/git-push-username-password-how-to-avoid)

Comment: Works! Thanks. You can re-check using the command `git remote -v`

Comment: Why is cloning with HTTPS a common mistake? GitHub now recommends using HTTPS.

Comment: @smftre by default that's the case, but you can use a [helper to cache your credentials](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache).

Comment: I've been using HTTPS for months now (with Git v1.8ish) without having to enter my username/password. Then I upgraded to Git v2.0.1 two days ago and I have to enter my username/password every single time I do `git push`. Please explain?

Comment: Fixed my `Permission denied (publickey)` using this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ .

Comment: Using SSH doesn't work when cloning submodules recursively AFAIK. Unless these submodules have an ssh url, but that is deprecated since it disallows users without a ssh setup to clone the repository recursively.

Comment: @chharvey And now GitHub recommends HTTPS again ! See https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/#next-steps-authenticating-to-github-from-git

Comment: git can also cache your username and password. It takes 30 seconds to set up. https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux

Comment: As per K M Rakibul Islam's answer below, If you are using Mac OSX, you can store you Github password in the keychain, so that do not need to enter you password each time, even over HTTPS. https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using a Stash server, but I had to put in the protocol ("ssh://") portion of the url for it to work for me:  `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@stash-server/my/app/repo.git`

Comment: Thanks to @BrunoBerisso for the comment on prepending credentials to the http(s) url.  If you still want some security and also a sanity check before pushing, you can omit your password from the url: `git remote set-url origin https://name@github.com/repo.git`.

Comment: I get `fatal: No such remote 'origin'`

Comment: Just thought I'd point out you can set ssh to use port 443 in various ways including your `~/.ssh/config` file in which case AFAIK anyone that can use https can use ssh with github at least as they support ssh on port 443. [example ~/.ssh/config](https://pastebin.com/0AThjxxV)

Comment: Note that to use the SSH method you will also need to set up an SSH key on your machine and associate it with your Github account.

Comment: I fixed the permission denied problem by renaming my private SSH key into `id_rsa`.

Comment: I also think that cloning with https is a bad idea because you are adding an extra mechanism that must be secured to allow pulling/pushing without enter the pass every time. With SSH you have the public key infrastructure that takes care of it. I don't know how secure is the caching mechanism but why to use it at all if ssh cloning gives you superpowers?

Comment: ```git remote set-url origin https://name@github.com/name/repo.git```

Comment: git remote set-url origin https://name:password@github.com/repo.git , If @ is present in password, you need to encode that with %40 like, pass@word -> pass%40word.

Comment: `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@host:port/user/repo.git` worked for me.

Answer (score 613):

#### Permanently authenticating with Git repositories

Run the following command to enable [credential caching](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux):

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push https://github.com/owner/repo.git

Username for 'https://github.com': <USERNAME>
Password for 'https://USERNAME@github.com': <PASSWORD>
```

---

You should also specify **caching expire**,

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout 7200'
```

After enabling credential caching, it will be cached for **7200 seconds (2 hour)**. 43,200 s = 12 h (login once per day) might also be a reasonable choice for some.

---

As [SebastianH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3239833/sebastianh) commented, can also use similar commands to configure this not per repository but globally:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 7200'
```

Comment: you may also have to change your remote url with `git remote set-url origin https://git@github.com/<owner>/<repo>.git`  This also works with 2FA

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It answer exactly the question.

Comment: will it be deleted automatically from the ubuntu files to after 7200 for security purpose ?

Comment: Just tried this - got: `fatal: protocol 'https' is not supported`

Comment: Does caching actually override anything from the store command? I'd think this answer is misleading as setting the cache options would be moot if you already have things stored permanently. No?

Comment: unfortunately i don't think this persist through reboots or after the expiry period thus if using 2FA one has to type the personal access token OVER and OVER, something i'd prefer to not have to do.

Comment: You can consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62184716/4575793) which  explaines that "You can also use `store` to store in a file on your local disk, which is available on all platforms, but less secure." There are different other **credential stores** as for example inbuilt for Linux and OS X [`git config --global credential.helper libsecret`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470658/4575793), for Windows `wincred` or the [CredentialManager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager#macos-homebrew) - which btw is available for both MacOS and Linux now.

Comment: I used git push and then wincred as authenticator and it worked!

Answer (score 162):

I just came across the same problem, and the simplest solution I found was to use SSH URL instead of HTTPS one:

```
ssh://git@github.com/username/repo.git
```

And not this:

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

You can now validate with *just* the SSH key instead of the `username` and `password`.

Comment: This worked for me but first I needed to address this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/git-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: to set up the SSH key you can refer to https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Comment: View current urls with `git remote -v` and set them with `git remote set-url --push origin`

Comment: i had some systems where SSH was not offered. so the respective admin seems to have opted for the also sort of secure https variant.

Answer (score 144):

Apart from changing to SSH you can also keep using HTTPS, if you don't mind to put your password in clear text. Put this in your `~/.netrc` and it won't ask for your username/password (at least on Linux and Mac):

```
machine github.com
       login <user>
       password <password>
```

**Addition** (see VonC's second comment): on Windows the file name is `%HOME%\_netrc`.

Also read VonC's first comment in case you want to encrypt.

**Another addition** (see user137717's comment) which you can use if you have **Git 1.7.10 or newer**.

[Cache your GitHub password in Git using a credential helper](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/):

> If you're cloning GitHub repositories using HTTPS, you can use a
>   credential helper to tell Git to remember your GitHub username and
>   password every time it talks to GitHub.

This also works on Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Comment: Yeah, it works on Linux, but doesn't work for gitbash on Windows.

Comment: @dolmen I see what you mean, but if you mind putting your password in a clear text, you can... encrypt it ;) See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309. and that is even compatible with the 2-factor authentication (2FA) of Github: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18607931/6309

Comment: @Sales it works perfectly from a DOS session or a git bash on Windows, provided you call your file `%HOME%\_netrc` (instead of `~/.netrc`). See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309 to encrypt that file.

Comment: This works very well in Linux, especially using git over VPN.

Comment: you don't need to put it in clear text or encrypt it. the helper utility will cache it for you and takes 30 seconds to set up. https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux

Comment: Why would you do this instead of just adding an SSH key?

Comment: This helped me. We can only connect to outside only  via https, all other outgoing ports are blocked.

Comment: `%HOME%` is only in Git Bash and is an absolute path. It does not exist in a CMD session. It seems to be a combination of %HOMEDRIVE% and %HOMEPATH% (but in Linux/Unix path format).

Comment: @Banjocat some companies (such as mine sadly), do not allow external outbound connections on port 22. So to access sites such as github.com passwordless, ssh keys are not useful as https must be used instead.

Comment: After hours surfing the net looking for answer this saved the day! Works very well for linux (Ubuntu) Thank you

Answer (score 106):

For the uninitiated who are confused by the previous answers, you can do:

```
git remote -v
```

Which will respond with something like

```
origin    https://yourname@github.com/yourname/yourrepo.git (fetch)
origin    https://yourname@github.com/yourname/yourrepo.git (push)
```

Then you can run the command many other have suggested, but now you know yourname and yourrepo from above, so you can just cut and paste `yourname/yourrepo.git` from the above into:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:yourname/yourrepo.git
```

Comment: I tried this. It asks me for `paraphrase` everytime. I didn't set up one

Comment: What goes in place of `yourrepo`?

Comment: @Raphi run `git remote -v` and see what comes out

Comment: Other answers should prepend this advice.

Comment: just a note, for repos under org instead of personal accounts, it seems to be: `https://github.com/orgname/yourrepo.git`

Answer (score 66):

If you're using SSH and your private key is encrypted with a passphrase, then ***you'll still be prompted to enter the passphrase/password for the private key when you do network operations with Git*** like `push`, `pull`, and `fetch`.

#### Use ssh-agent to save the private key passphrase/password credentials

If you want to avoid having to enter your passphrase every time, you can use `ssh-agent` to store your private key passphrase credentials once per terminal session, as I explain in [my answer to *Could not open a connection to your authentication agent*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/17848593#17848593):

```bash
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
$ ssh-add
```

In a Windows msysgit Bash, you need to evaluate the output of `ssh-agent`, but I'm not sure if you need to do the same in other development environments and operating systems.

`ssh-add` looks for a private key in your home `.ssh` folder called `id_rsa`, which is the default name, but you can pass a filepath to a key with a different name.

#### Killing the agent

When you're done with your terminal session, you can shutdown `ssh-agent` with the kill flag `-k`:

```bash
$ ssh-agent -k
```

As explained in the [`ssh-agent` manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-agent):

> ```
> -k
> ```
>
> Kill the current agent (given by the SSH_AGENT_PID environment variable).

#### Optional timeout

Also, it can take an optional timeout parameter like so:

```bash
$ ssh-add -t <timeout>
```

where `<timeout>` is of the format `<n>h` for `<n>` hours, `<n>m` for `<n>` minutes, and so on.

According to the [`ssh-agent` manual](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-agent):

> ```
> -t life
> ```
>
> Set a default value for the maximum lifetime of identities added to the agent. The lifetime may be specified in seconds or in a
>   time format specified in [sshd_config(5)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current). A lifetime specified for an identity with [ssh-add(1)](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-add&sektion=1&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current) overrides this value. Without this option the default maximum lifetime is forever.

[See this page for more time formats](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5&arch=&apropos=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current#end).

#### Security warning for Cygwin users

Cygwin users should be aware of a [potential security risk with using ssh-agent in Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-06/msg00537.html):

> people should be cognizant of the
>   potential dangers of ssh-agent under Cygwin [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/17848593#17848593), though under a local netstat and remote portscan it does not appear that the port specified in /tmp/ssh-foo is accessible to anyone ...?
>
> ```
> [1]: http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-01/msg00063.html
> ```

And at the [cited link](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2001-01/msg00063.html):

> however, note that Cygwin's Unix domain sockets are *FUNDAMENTALLY INSECURE* and so I strongly *DISCOURAGE* usage of ssh-agent under Cygwin.
>
> when you run ssh-agent under Cygwin it creates AF_UNIX socket in `/tmp/ssh-$USERNAME/` directory. Under Cygwin AF_UNIX sockets are emulated via AF_INET sockets. You can easily see that if you'll look into `/tmp/ssh-$USERNAME/agent-socket-*` file via Notepad. You'll see something like
>
> ```
> !<socket >2080
> ```
>
> then run `netstat -a` and surprise! You have some program listening to port 2080. It's  ssh-agent. When ssh receives an RSA challenge from the server, it  refers to corresponding `/tmp/ssh-$USERNAME/agent-socket-*` (under Cygwin, in our case, that means it'll open connection to `localhost:2080`) and asks ssh-agent  to process the RSA challenge with the private key it has, and then it simply passes the response received from the ssh-agent to the server.
>
> Under Unix, such a scenario works without problems, because the Unix kernel checks permissions when the program tries to access an AF_UNIX socket. For AF_INET sockets, however, connections are anonymous (read
>   "insecure"). Imagine, that you have the Cygwin ssh-agent  running. A malicious hacker may portscan your box, locate open port used by ssh-agent, open a connection to your SSH server, receive the RSA challenge from it, send it to your ssh-agent via an open port he/she found, receive the RSA response, send it to the SSH server and voila, he/she successfully logged in to your server as you.

Comment: Sounds nice and detailed. I took care of [https credential helper](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309), and you took care of ssh connections! +1

Comment: fantastic. This has actually helped me because my situation was a bit different, as even though my remote was set to 'ssh' instead of 'https' it was still asking for a password to be entered every time when I issued `git push` , `git pull` etc, and I was not liking the suggestions of storing the creds though it is my personal machine (as a best practice). This suggestion of `ssh-add` really helped. Thank you  :)

Answer (score 60):

Source: [Set Up Git](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/)

The following command will save your password in memory for some time (for **Git 1.7.10** or newer).

```sh
$ git config --global credential.helper cache
# Set git to use the credential memory cache

$ git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
# Set the cache to timeout after one hour (setting is in seconds)
```

Comment: I prefer the 'netrc' credential help (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309) for caching *multiple* credentials (without having to remember every passwords). But if you are on Windows and want to use the memory cache, you need winstore (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15310274/6309)

Comment: This is is the best answer thus far IMHO.

Answer (score 42):

When you use **https** for Git pull & push, just configure `remote.origin.url` for your project, to avoid input username (or/and password) every time you push.

**How to configure `remote.origin.url`:**

```
URL format:
    https://{username:password@}github.com/{owner}/{repo}

Parameters in URL:

* username 

    Optional, the username to use when needed. 
 authentication,
    if specified, no need to enter username again when need authentication.
    Don't use email; use your username that has no "@", otherwise the URL can't be parsed correctly,
* password
    optional, the password to use when need authentication.
    If specified, there isn't any need to enter the password again when needing authentication.
    Tip:
        this value is stored as plain text, so for security concerns, don't specify this parameter,
*

e.g
    git config remote.origin.url https://eric@github.com/eric/myproject
```

---

### @Update - using `ssh`

I think using `ssh` protocol is a better solution than `https`, even though the setup step is a little more complex.

**Rough steps:**

- Create ssh keys using command, e.g `ssh-keygen` on Linux, on windows `msysgit` provide similar commands.
- Keep the private key on the local machine at a proper location, e.g., `~/.ssh`. And add it to the ssh agent via `ssh-add` command.
- Upload the public key to the Git server.
- Change `remote.origin.url` of the Git repository to `ssh` style, e.g., `git@gitlab.com:myaccount/myrepo.git`
- Then when pull or push, there isn't any need to enter the username or password ever.

**Tips:**

- If your ssh key has a passphrase, then you need to input it on first use of the key after each restart of your machine, by default.

---

### @Update - Switch between `https` and `ssh` protocol.

Simply changing `remote.origin.url` will be enough, or you can edit `repo_home/.git/config` directly to change the value (e.g using `vi` on Linux).

Usually I add a line for each protocol, and comment out one of them using `#`.

**E.g.**

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@gitlab.com:myaccount/myrepo.git
        # url = https://myaccount@gitlab.com/myaccount/myrepo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Are you sure the **http[s]**-based URL support username expansion?  The manual `git-fetch(1)` mentions that only for `git`/`ssh`-based URLs.

Comment: @plmday yes, I am using it, my git version is 1.8.2.3 and 1.8.4, I am not sure if higher verion do change about this.

Comment: NB providing your password in the URL (even when using HTTPS) means that it is visible to everything between you and your repository.

Comment: No, providing the password in `https://username:password@github.com/` is safe. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980912/username-and-password-in-https-url

Comment: And this was what I was looking for (for full automation)

Comment: @Joshua The answer is old, `ssh` is actually a better solution, it's full automation too, I use `ssh` now unless when it's not working due to network issue.

Comment: @flybird: Can't use ssh because the server doesn't support it.

Comment: This https technique worked for me on Github. However, remember that username on Github is not your email address. Yes, on Github, you can login with either in the username field. However, for git commits, you must specifically use your username.

Comment: Thanks, the last hack - editing `repo_home/.git/config` did the job for me. I'd already setup ssh keys before that.

Answer (score 18):

If you've **got 2FA enabled** on your Github account, your regular password won't work for this purpose, but you can generate a Personal Access Token and use that in its place instead.

Visit the `Settings` -> `Developer Settings` -> `Personal Access Tokens` page in GitHub (https://github.com/settings/tokens/new), and generate a new Token with all **Repo** permissions:

[image: generate GitHub personal access token]

The page will then display the new token value. Save this value and use it in place of your password when pushing to your repository on GitHub:

```
> git push origin develop
Username for 'https://github.com': <your username>
Password for 'https://<your username>@github.com': <your personal access token>
```

Comment: For security purposes, I find this to be the best https option. Storing a key seems to be a much better idea than storing your master password in plain text somewhere. The cache options provide additional layers of protection, by only allowing someone to interact if the current user on your machine, but if someone were to have access to your computer in the time before the cache dropped, there is still the potential risk. With this, even if the worst case scenario above occurred, you could just go remove the key from github from another computer.

Comment: I think you'd still need to add `git config credential.helper store` prior to pushing or otherwise interacting with the remote, otherwise this token would be no longer be present next time you went to interact with the remote. Right?

Comment: @topher217: that's correct. You can use the Git credential helper or even something like Mac OSX's Keychain to store these tokens for repeated use.

Comment: @topher you can consider [this answer and my respective comment *(scroll up from there)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password/28562712#comment130679949_28562712) about the security of different credential helpers. `store` is the most insecure one, as it just plainly saves (stores) the content. There are more secure ones available.

Answer (score 17):

You can cache your GitHub password in Git:

Just follow the instructions from GitHub's [official documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/).

After following the instructions from the above link, you should be able to push/pull to/from your repository without typing your username/password every time.

Comment: this is the best answer here and should be the accepted one IMO

Comment: Agreed, an answer citing the official documentation should take precedence. I gladly followed their instructions and prefer to use standard conventions.

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me was to edit `.git/config` and use

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://<login>:<password>@gitlab.com(...).git
```

It goes without saying that this is an insecure way of storing your password but there are environments/cases where this may not be a problem.

Answer (score 14):

Here's another option:

Instead of writing

```
git push origin HEAD
```

You could write:

```
git push https://user:pass@yourrepo.com/path HEAD
```

Obviously, with most shells this will result in the password getting cached in history, so keep that in mind.

Comment: In Bash, adding one or more *leading* spaces will usually keep it out of history. But not in [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), though.

Answer (score 14):

## For Mac OS

1. Go to your Github `Settings` -> `Developer Settings` -> `Personal Access Tokens` page in GitHub (https://github.com/settings/tokens/new), and generate a new Token with all Repo permissions
2. Search Keychain Access in your mac -> search for `github.com`  -> click `Show password` then paste the `token` you just copied.
3. Go to the CLI, it will again ask for your username and password, enter your Github username and paste the token as password, and you should be good to go for the rest of the times you are using the CLI.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. One thing to add, if `github.com` is not found in Keychain Access, that's ok, just do step 3 and then it will show in the keychain access.

Answer (score 11):

If the SSH key or `.netrc` file did not work for you, then another simple, but less secure solution, that could work for you is [git-credential-store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) - Helper to store credentials on disk:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

By default, credentials will be saved in file `~/.git-credentials`. It will be created and written to.

Please note using this helper will store your passwords unencrypted on disk, protected only by filesystem permissions. If this may not be an acceptable security tradeoff.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue.

So I changed the `.git/config` file from my project,

```
url = https://github.com/<your-user-here>/<your-repo-here>
```

to

```
url = git@github.com:<your-user-here>/<your-repo-here>
```

and added the SSH public key to the Git profile which is in setting.

For the SSH public key:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: with `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` get the rsa key and paste in git web portal setting.

Answer (score 7):

If you have cloned HTTPS instead of SSH and facing issue with username and password prompt on pull, push and fetch. You can solve this problem simply for UBUNTU

Step 1:
move to root directory

```
cd ~/
```

create a file .git-credentials

Add this content to that file with you `usename` `password` and `githosting URL`

```
https://user:pass@example.com
```

Then execute the command

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Now you will be able to pull push and fetch all details from your repo without any hassle.

Comment: what a the `githosting URL`? For example, what would that be for `Gitlab`

Answer (score 6):

**Updating your Git configuration file directly (*if you do not want to memorize fancy commands*):**

Open your `.git/config` file in your favorite text editor. It will be in the folder that you cloned or in the repository that you performed `git init` in. Go into that repository. `.git` is a hidden folder, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> should show the hidden folder, (`ls -a` in terminal).

Below is a sample of the `.git/config` file. Copy and paste these lines and be sure to update those lines with your Git information.

```
[user]
        name = Tux
        email = tux@gmail.com
        username = happy_feet

[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/happy_feet/my_code.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Change the URL part with the following format for SSH:

```
url = git@github.com:happy_feet/my_code.git
```

(*The above formats do not change with various Git remote servers like GitHub or Bitbucket. It's the same if you are using Git for version control*):

**Note:** The SSH way of connecting to a remote Git repository will require you to add your public SSH key to your Git remote server (*like GitHub or Bitbucket. Search the settings page for SSH keys*).

*To know how to generate your SSH keys, refer to:* 
*[Creating SSH keys](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html)*

Comment: The good thing about setting [user] is that if you have a master git credential even then the commits will be registered by the [user] in the config.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my working solution which passes 2FA as well.

1. Login to github on your browser.
2. Go to this page and create a token
   https://github.com/settings/tokens
3. Copy the generated token string.
4. Enter this command in terminal with your own values

`git remote set-url origin https://{yourAccountName}:{theCopiedToken}@github.com/{yourAccountName}/{repositoryName}.git`

**Now you are logged in and can push/pull, etc.**

Answer (score 5):

You basically have two options.

If you use the same user on both machines you need to copy the .pub key to your PC, so GitHub knows that you are the same user.

If you have created a new .pub file for your PC and want to treat the machines as different users, you need to register the new .pub file on the GitHub website.

If this still doesn't work it might be because ssh is not configured correctly and that ssh fail to find the location of your keys. Try

```
ssh -vv username@github.com
```

To get more information why SSH fails.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows Git users, after running `git config --global credential.helper store`, if it still prompts for a password, you'd better check where the configuration file is written to, using this command

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

In my case, after manually editing configuration file 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\gitconfig', and adding the following text, it worked.

```
[credential]
    helper = store
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

```
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

Example:

```
git remote set-url origin https://jsmith@github.com/jsmith/master.git
```

Answer (score 5):

List your current SSH keys:

```
ls -l ~/.ssh
```

Generate a new SSH key:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

where you should replace `your_email@example.com` with your GitHub email
address.
When prompted to `Enter a file in which to save the key`, press
<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Upon `Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase)` - just press
<kbd>Enter</kbd> (for an empty passphrase).
List the your SSH keys again:

```
ls -l ~/.ssh
```

The files `id_ed25519` and `id_ed25519.pub` should now have been added.
Start the ssh-agent in the background:

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
```

Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Next output the public key to the terminal screen:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

Copy the output to the clipboard
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>).
Go to `https://github.com/<your-github-username>` and sign in with your
username and password.
Click your GitHub avatar in the upper-right corner, and then **Settings**.
In the left pane click **SSH and GPG keys**.
Click the green-colored button **New SSH key**
and paste the public SSH key into the textarea labeled **Key**.
Use a descriptive **Title** that tells from what computer you will
use this SSH key. Click **Add SSH key**.

---

If your current local repository was created with **http** and **username**,
it needs to be recreated it so as to become SSH compatible.
First check to make sure that you have a clean working tree
so that you don't lose any work:

```
git status
```

Then `cd ..` to the parent directory and `rm -fr <name-of-your-repo>`.
Finally clone a fresh copy that uses SSH instead of username/password:

```
git clone git@github.com:[your-github-username]/[repository-name].git
```

References:
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Answer (score 4):

**Update for HTTPS:**

GitHub has launched a new program for Windows that stores your credentials when you're using HTTPS:

To use:

- Download the program from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git)
- Once you run the program, it will edit your `.gitconfig` file. Recheck if it edited the correct `.gitconfig` in case you have several of them. If it didn't edit the correct one, add the following to your `.gitconfig`

  ```
  [credential]
      helper = !'C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Downloaded\\File\\git-credential-winstore.exe'
  ```

  NOTE the line break after `[credential]`. It is required.
- Open up your command line client and try `git push origin master` once. If it asks you for a password, enter it and you're through. Password saved!

Answer (score 4):

You need to perform two steps -

1. `git remote remove origin`
2. `git remote add origin git@github.com:NuggetAI/nugget.git`

Notice the Git URL is a SSH URL and not an HTTPS URL... Which you can select from here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of 2021, there is a **secure user-friendly cross-platform** solution for HTTPS remotes. No more typing passwords! No more SSH keys! No more personal access tokens!

**Install [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager)** developed by GitHub ([downloads](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/latest)). It supports passwordless in-browser OAuth authentication to GitHub, BitBucket, Azure and GitLab. This means you can enable [two-factor authentication on GitHub](https://github.com/settings/security) and the other platforms, greatly improving the security of your accounts.

When you push, you are offered a choice of authentication methods:

```
> git push
Select an authentication method for 'https://github.com/':
  1. Web browser (default)
  2. Device code
  3. Personal access token
option (enter for default): 1
info: please complete authentication in your browser...
```

**On Linux, a tiny bit of setup** is required. The following caches credentials in memory for 20 hours, so you have to authenticate at most once per day.

```
git-credential-manager-core configure
git config --global credential.credentialStore cache
git config --global credential.cacheoptions "--timeout 72000"
```

Power users familiar with gnome-keyring or KWallet may prefer to [change the credential store](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/credstores.md#freedesktoporg-secret-service-api) to libsecret.

**Cosmetic configuration** ([docs](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/configuration.md)):

1. Prefer choosing authentication method at terminal rather than in GUI (fewer clicks)
2. Always use browser method rather than be asked every time (even fewer keypresses)

```
git config --global credential.guiPrompt false
git config --global credential.gitHubAuthModes browser
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Git (for example, Git Bash) under Windows 
(and if you don't want to switch from HTTPS to SSH), you could also use *[Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)*

This application will keep the username and password for you...

Answer (score 1):

> Blockquote

if you experience $ git push code issues requesting for username && password follow the procedure below:

```
Login to your profile.
Go to settings

click developer settings
->Personal access tokens
--> note: access token
--->Select scopes: checkbox on repo
----> Generate token
-----> Make sure to copy and store it safely if you intend to reuse it.

*** use the generated token as password during pushing code for next 30days ***

***HAPPY CODING***
```

Answer (score 0):

As many users has said, you just have to change your Git repository URL from HTTPS to SSH.

If you haven't generated a SSH key in your machine, then your are going to have to do it.

Just as an additional information, after doing this change I still was getting the same error:

> Permission Denied.

In my case, the problem was that I was using the Windows Shell to execute the ngh command; since this command should open a prompt to request the SSH phrase and the Windows Shell doesn't open these kinds of prompts, the authentication just failed.

So, I just had to open the Git shell and execute the ngh command there, put the SSH phrase in the prompt every time it asked for it and "voilà"... It just worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
 # gen  the pub and priv keys
 # use "strange" naming convention, because those WILL BE more than 10 ...
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "me@corp.com" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.me@corp.com@`hostname -s`

 # set the git alias ONLY this shell session
 alias git='GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.me@corp.com.`hostname -s`" git'

 # who did what when and why
 git log --pretty --format='%h %ai %<(15)%ae ::: %s'

 # set the git msg
 export git_msg='issue-123 my important commit msg'

 # add all files ( danger !!! ) and commit them with the msg
 git add --all ; git commit -m "$git_msg" --author "Me <me@corp.com"

 # finally 
 git push
```

Answer (score -1):

### Your git and/or SSH version is too old

I was affected by both ssh and git always prompting for passwords on my 2010 Macbook Pro running Snow Leopard.

Originally, I was unable to ssh into my server.

I had enabled `HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa,ssh-dss` on my server (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) which I host my git repos and ssh into my accounts. With that change, I was able to use a username and password to connect to git and through ssh.

For reference the latest versions of ssh and git on OS X 10.6.8 are:

`git: 1.7.5.4`

`ssh: OpenSSH_5.2p1`

I tried adding a DSA key, but that didn't work. I also looked into updating the RSA1 key, but it looked like my SSH version was simply too old.
I looked into Homebrew for snow leopard, but got certificate issues.

My solution is to install MacPorts for Snow Leopard https://github.com/macports/macports-base/releases/download/v2.8.1/MacPorts-2.8.1-10.6-SnowLeopard.pkg

I had the xcode 4.2 update installed which may be hard to find; not sure if that is necessary. Once MacPorts is installed, run

```
sudo port install git
sudo port install ssh
```

You may have to enable rsync, but the output will tell you how.

My versions are now `2.41.0` for git and `OpenSSH_9.3p1` for ssh. I recreated a 4096 bit rsa key and copied it to my server (and to github) and can now both `ssh` and `git push` without any password prompting at all!

Hope this helps out others in my position.

Edit: Gentoo mentioned that since OpenSSH 8.8, support for RSA 1 is disabled (my server being `OpenSSH_9.3p1`). It can be re-enabled by adding this:

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

If you are using PuTTY < 0.75, you will be affected by this.

Comment: Also if you are going to down vote me, at least give a reason as to why. I got the symptoms that the original asker mentioned and my fix enables me to overcome the problem. Just because I answered using my personal server doesn't mean it doesn't work on github either. In fact, I tested it by checking out one of my repos on github (I was previously unable to do so) and I can check out without using a password. So it works.

Answer (score -2):

Check your git version and update. Then will fixed the issue

`$ git update-git-for-windows`

Update note : we can use this when your PC git version and server git version mismatched.

Comment: This command doesn't work for me at all. No such command.

Comment: This worked only the windows 10 and that server git version miss with your computer version.