# How do I avoid the specification of the username and password at every git push?

Tags: git, github, git-push

I `git push` my work to a remote Git repository.

Every `push` will prompt me to input `username` and `password`. I would like to avoid it for every push, but how to configure to avoid it?

Comment: An answer is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password

Comment: Long story short: For github, Just follow these two links https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url

Comment: for bitbucket please follow [this link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)

Answer (score 448, accepted):

## 1. Generate an SSH key

#### Linux/Mac

Open terminal to create ssh keys:

```
cd ~                 #Your home directory
ssh-keygen -t rsa    #Press enter for all values
```

#### For Windows

(Only works if the commit program is capable of using certificates/private & public ssh keys)

1. Use Putty Gen to generate a key
2. Export the key as an open SSH key

Here is a [walkthrough](http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_create_and_use_public_keys_with_ssh.html) on putty gen for the above steps

## 2. Associate the SSH key with the remote repository

This step varies, depending on how your remote is set up.

- If it is a GitHub repository and you have administrative privileges, go to [**settings**](https://github.com/settings/ssh) and click 'add SSH key'. Copy the contents of your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into the field labeled 'Key'.
- If your repository is administered by somebody else, give the administrator your `id_rsa.pub`.
- If your remote repository is administered by your, you can use this command for example:

  `scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub YOUR_USER@YOUR_IP:~/.ssh/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub`

## 3. Set your remote URL to a form that supports SSH <sup>1</sup>

If you have done the steps above and are still getting the password prompt, make sure your repo URL is in the form

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

as opposed to

```
https://github.com/username/reponame.git
```

To see your repo URL, run:

```
git remote show origin
```

You can change the URL with:

```
git remote set-url origin git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

<sub>[1] This section incorporates the answer from [Eric P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1094910/eric-p)</sub>

Comment: On Windows: If you are using the git bash window the **terminal** commands also work. The only thing is you must be certain you want to overwrite the default id_rsa file, and you must type `y` when prompted if you want to overwrite the current id_rsa key.

Comment: I ran step 1 and step 2 on ubuntu but it still asks me for u_id passwd. I also ran: ssh -T git@github.com. Still the same. What to do?

Comment: @Rads Have you tried the other answer, by **Eric P**?

Comment: @dialex He meant a person that administrates the remote git repository.

Comment: Well that person is me, on GitHub. It's my account. Can anyone refer me a link explaining how to perform that last step?

Comment: git remote set-url origin git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git  this command is helpful to me.

Comment: I followed these steps exactly, but am now getting
"Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository."
What's worse is I can't undo the changes, making me unable to use the git repo at all. I've removed the public key from github and removed github from known hosts, and deleted the keys generated, but still can't get back to the password prompt.

Comment: Step 2 needs more info for people not pushing to GitHub and who are administering their own repo remotely. How do you associate the SSH key with the repo??

Comment: The `git+ssh` option does not seem to work if my local username is different from my github username.

Comment: A command that is useful to copy the contents of the public key and give yourself access to a github repo from a new machine/newly minted rsa key is to use: `clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and paste that content as a new SSH key in the "SSH and GPG Keys" section of your GitHub Settings.

Comment: step 2 of this answer is not clear for me, I don't have the `~/.ssh` folder in my remote repo.

Comment: "If your remote repository is administered by your [sic], you can use this command for example". Your what?

Comment: This worked for me `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:/username/projectname.git`

Comment: I met some problem on: How to avoid input username and passwd everytime when make git push?

1) my system is Ubuntu 18.04
2) I created id_rsa.pub and copy it to github website setting page. 
3) However, I am still require to input username and passwd when I make `git push` operation. 
4) I also tried  --globe user.name and user.pasword, however, i was still require passwd when I make `git push` operation. 
5) No respose when I use `ssh -T git@github.com` to test SSH connection.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: I'm going to add that git will only take your public key if you name it exactly "id_rsa". If your public/private keys are named in any other way, you will get the following error - 

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: Note that RSA, especially with its default 1024-bit key is no longer considered secure. Either using 4096+ bits or switching to ed25519 appears to be the current recommendation. See: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/143442/111605

Comment: Note that there are handy scripts to automate step 3, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/m14t/3056747)

Answer (score 223):

#### Permanently authenticating with Git repositories,

Run the following command to enable credential caching.

```
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git push https://github.com/repo.git

Username for 'https://github.com': <USERNAME>
Password for 'https://USERNAME@github.com': <PASSWORD>
```

---

Use should also specify **caching expire**,

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout 7200'
```

After enabling credential caching, it will be cached for **7200 seconds (2 hours)**.

**Note:** *Credential helper stores an unencrypted password on a local disk.*

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what the config command does ? I wonder why it does not even ask me for a password the first time I push to a repo.

Comment: @vivoconunxino Probably because it's inherently unsafe. From the `git` manpage: "Using this helper will store your passwords unencrypted on disk, protected only by filesystem permissions."

Comment: **This answer is missing a warning about the `store` credential helper storing the password on disk unencrypted.**

Comment: I really like this solution because for some circumstances, a lot of developers can't authenticate with ssh keys to push to their repos. This is a viable workaround if you have to necessarily do https.

Comment: @JayPatel - How do I disable `git config credential.helper store` if I do not want it any more?

Comment: @DavidRTribble: set it to cache? Or remove the relevant file, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Comment: @DavidRTribble: better: `git config --unset credential.helper`

Comment: Also note that, push isn't necessary, any command which asks for credentials like git fetch will also work. Command git push might give a wrong impression that any config is being pushed to the remote.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica, just to confirm, where exactly `git` stores those credentials? I mean in which file at which location?

Comment: @Milan `man git-credential-store` lists the files `~/.git-credentials` and `XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/credentials`, in that order. Along with the note: "Using this helper will store your passwords unencrypted on disk, protected only by filesystem permissions."

Answer (score 128):

If you already have your SSH keys set up and are still getting the password prompt, make sure your repo URL is in the form

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

as opposed to

```
https://github.com/username/reponame.git
```

To see your repo URL, run:

```
git remote show origin
```

You can change the URL with `git remote set-url` like so:

```
git remote set-url origin git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

Comment: This is what fixed my problem after I had used `git init` locally, then tried to push after adding the remote from a new repo on the GitHub website.

Comment: Not sure why this is not part of the accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Accepted answer should be composed of actual accepted answer PLUS this one.

Comment: You can omit the "git+ssh://" and just use `git@github.com/username/reponame.git`

Comment: @IvanShulev I did try initially without git+ssh and didn't worked

Comment: In case it's a GitHub repo you can automate the change from https to git+ssh by using ``git remote set-url origin `git remote get-url origin | awk -F/ '{ print "git+ssh://git@github.com/" $(NF-1) "/" $(NF) }'``

Answer (score 42):

Just use `--repo` option for git push command. Like this:

```
$ git push --repo https://name:password@bitbucket.org/name/repo.git
```

Comment: Or you can set this by default with `git remote set-url origin https://name:password@github.com/repo.git`

Comment: I note setting the URL to just a `name@github.com/....git` works too if you don't mind being nagged for the password each time.

Comment: For github users, `git push --repo https://github.com/Username/repo
` It does work without the `.git ` extension

Answer (score 34):

#### Saving Indefinitely

You can use the [git-credential-store](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store) via

```
git config credential.helper store
```

which [stores your password unencrypted in the file system](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store):

> Using this helper will store your passwords unencrypted on disk, protected only by filesystem permissions. If this is not an acceptable security tradeoff, try git-credential-cache, or find a helper that integrates with secure storage provided by your operating system.

#### With a Timeout

Use the [git-credential-cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) which by default stores the password for 15 minutes.

```
git config credential.helper cache
```

to set a different timeout, use `--timeout` (here 5 minutes)

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=300'
```

#### [Secure Saving Indefinitely](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) (OS X and Windows)

> - If you’re using a Mac, Git comes with an **“osxkeychain” mode**, which caches credentials in the secure keychain that’s attached to your system account. This method stores the credentials on disk, and they never expire, but they’re encrypted with the same system that stores HTTPS certificates and Safari auto-fills. Running the following on the command line will enable this feature: `git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain`. You'll need to store the credentials in the Keychain using the Keychain app as well.
> - If you’re using Windows, you can **install a helper called “Git Credential Manager for Windows.”** This is similar to the “osxkeychain” helper described above, but uses the Windows Credential Store to control sensitive information. It can be found at https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows. [emphases mine]

Comment: For Windows `credential.helper cache` does NOT work. It should be `git config --global credential.helper wincred`.

Comment: This is helpful when you are forced to use https. My git on the server hangs if I use ssh, so I don't have the option of SSH keys.

Answer (score 8):

I was using the https link (`https://github.com/org/repo.git`)
instead of the ssh link;

```
git@github.com:org/repo.git
```

Switching solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 7):

Step 1 -

Create SSH keys on your linux system using below command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email"
```

It will ask for passphrase and file name (default will be ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)

Step 2 -

Once files created add public key id_rsa.pub to github account ssh section.

Step 3 -

On your machine add private key id_rsa to ssh-agent using below command

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Step 4 -

Now add remote url git@github.com:user_name/repo_name.git to your local git repo using below command.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:user_name/repo_name.git
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows operating system use this instead, this works for me:

```
https://{Username}:{Password}@github.com/{Username}/{repo}.git
```

e.g.

```
git clone https://{Username}:{Password}@github.com/{Username}/{repo}.git

git pull https://{Username}:{Password}@github.com/{Username}/{repo}.git

git remote add origin https://{Username}:{Password}@github.com/{Username}/{repo}.git

git push origin master
```

Answer (score 5):

Wire your git client to your OS credential store. For example in Windows you bind the credential helper to wincred:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

[Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github)

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to point out something about the solution said above several times:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

You can use any command that requires a password after this. You don't have to push. (you can also pull for instance) After that, you won't need to type in your username / password again.

Answer (score 4):

If your PC is secure or you don't care about password security, this can be achieved very simply.  Assuming that the remote repository is on GitHub and `origin` is your local name for the remote repository, use this command

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://<username>:<password>@github.com/<repo>
```

The `--push` flag ensures this changes the URL of the repository for the `git push` command only.  (The question asked in the original post is about `git push` command only.  Requiring a username+password only for push operations is the normal setup for *public* repositories on GitHub . Note that *private* repositories on GitHub would also require a username+password for pull and fetch operations, so for a private repository you would not want to use the `--push flag` ...)

**WARNING:** This is inherently unsecure because:

1. your ISP, or anyone logging your network accesses, can easily
   see the password in plain text in the URL;
2. anyone who gains access to your PC can view your password using `git remote show origin`.

That's why using an SSH key is the accepted answer.

Even an SSH key is *not totally secure*.  Anyone who gains access to your PC can still, for example, make pushes which wreck your repository or - worse - push commits making subtle changes to your code. (All pushed commits are obviously highly visible on GitHub. But if someone wanted to change your code surreptitiously, they could `--amend` a previous commit without changing the commit message, and then force push it. That would be stealthy and quite hard to notice in practice.)

But revealing your password is *worse*.  If an attacker gains knowledge of your username+password, they can do things like lock you out of your own account, delete your account, permanently delete the repository, etc.

---

Alternatively - for simplicity *and* security - you can supply **only your username** in the URL, so that you will have to type your password every time you `git push` but you will not have to give your username each time.  (I quite like this approach, having to type the password gives me a pause to think each time I `git push`, so I cannot `git push` by accident.)

```
git remote set-url --push origin https://<username>@github.com/<repo>
```

Comment: what if password has `@`, it is breaking command thinking password after @ as part of git server?

Comment: If your password contains '@' you're on your own here, sorry.  You can change your password?

Comment: Need to raise request to change password as I was doing automation for Continuous Integration having service account(not personal). Right now used SSH Keys for secure login

Comment: `git remote set-url --push origin https://<username>@github.com/<repo>` needs to be `git remote set-url --push origin https://<username>@github.com/<username>/<repo>`

Answer (score 4):

Running the below command solved the problem for me.

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Please refer the below github documentation:

```
https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the answer that Pavel suggested and it worked for me. My difference was to do it while I was adding the remote like so: `git remote add (alias) https://(name:password)@github.com/(the remote address).git`

Answer (score 3):

My Solution on Windows:

1. Right click at directory to push and select "Git Bash Here".
2. `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (Press enter for all values)
3. Check terminal for: `Your public key has been saved in /c/Users/<your_user_name_here>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
4. Copy public key from specified file.
5. Go to your GitHub profile => Settings => SSH and GPG keys => New SSH key => Paste your SSH key there => Save

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there are simply two *safe* ways: *ssh* or *passwd encrypted using a keystore*.

#### SSH

1. Log in your github;
2. Visit: https://github.com/settings/keys;
3. New SSH key;
4. `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, paste it there, name and save it (if you have no such file, generate one for yourself by `ssh-keygen -t rsa` - just *Enter* for all prompts);
5. Go to your local repository and update your remote by `git remote set-url origin git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git` - you can check it first by `git remote -v`);
6. Here you go, just `touch t; git add t; git commit -m "test"; git push` and confirm yes to enjoy the *password-free* world.

#### passwd ENCRYPTED using a keystore

If you just use `git config --global credential.helper store` as others mentioned, your **unencrypted** passwords will be just stored in a plain text under `~/.git-credentials` which is not safe as it sounds.

Try to *encrypt* it as

```
sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev
sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring

git config --global credential.helper store
```

> In this case, you are using `https://git@github.com/username/reponame.git`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using a credential manager to store the GitHub credentials. Using `git config --global credential.helper store` is not safe as it stores the GitHub password in clear text.
For Linux, [libsecret](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libsecret) is an excellent alternative. For Ubuntu and some other linux distributions you can do the following:

**Install:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
sudo apt install gnome-keyring
```

**Create**

```
cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/
sudo make
```

**Configure git to store passwords using libsecret**

```
git config --global credentail.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

Your git credentials will be stored by libsecret after you enter your password **once** after this setup.

Answer (score 1):

All this arises because git does not provide an option in clone/pull/push/fetch commands to send the credentials through a pipe. Though it gives credential.helper, it stores on the file system or creates a daemon etc. Often, the credentials of GIT are system level ones and onus to keep them safe is on the application invoking the git commands. Very unsafe indeed.

Here is what I had to work around.
1. Git version (git --version) should be greater than or equal to 1.8.3.

**GIT CLONE**

For cloning, use "git clone URL" after changing the URL from the format, http://{myuser}@{my_repo_ip_address}/{myrepo_name.git} to http://{myuser}:{mypwd}@{my_repo_ip_address}/{myrepo_name.git}

Then purge the repository of the password as in the next section.

**PURGING**

Now, this would have gone and

1. written the password in git remote origin. Type "git remote -v" to see the damage. Correct this by setting the remote origin URL without password. "git remote set_url origin http://{myuser}@{my_repo_ip_address}/{myrepo_name.git}"
2. written the password in .git/logs in the repository. Replace all instances of pwd using a unix command like find .git/logs -exec sed -i 's/{my_url_with_pwd}//g' {} \; 
   Here, {my_url_with_pwd} is the URL with password. Since the URL has forward slashes, it needs to be escaped by two backward slashes. For ex, for the URL http://kris:passs123@192.168.0.1/proj.git -> http:\\/\\/kris:passs123@192.168.0.1\\/proj.git

If your application is using Java to issue these commands, use ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime. If you must use Runtime, use getRunTime().exec which takes String array as arguments with /bin/bash and -c as arguments rather then the one which takes a single String as argument.

**GIT FETCH/PULL/PUSH**

1. set password in the git remote url as :  "git remote set_url origin http://{myuser}:{mypwd}@{my_repo_ip_address}/{myrepo_name.git}"
2. Issue the command git fetch/push/pull. You will not then be prompted for the password.
3. Do the purging as in the previous section. Do not miss it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a SSH private key, you can review this [page](http://help.github.com/mac-set-up-git/), how to do the setup on Mac, if you are on linux the guide should be almost the same, on Windows you would need tool like [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS).

Answer (score 0):

Appears that, at least when using TortoiseGIT on Windows, it is possible to create the SSH keys and transfer these to the GIT server using simply:

```
> ssh-keygen.exe
> ssh-copy-id [username]@[GIT_server]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using SSH, after adding the public key to GitHub, then setting the remote to something like git@github.com/username/reponame.git, as well as  permanently adding the private key locally worked. The local commands where:

ssh-add

ssh-add -K

I guess the latter step might be missing for some people.