# Configuring user and password with Git Bash

Tags: git, github, credentials

I am using Git Bash on Windows 7. We are using GitHub as our repository origin.

Every time I push or pull I have to provide user and password credentials. I know that my SSH keys are set up correctly, otherwise I would not be able to access the repository. (That is, once I enter my credentials the push/pull works correctly.)

I have entered

```
git config --global user.name myusername
git config --global user.email myemail
git config --global github.user myusername
git config --global github.token mytoken
```

But nonetheless I am being asked for credentials each and every time I push/pull.

Comment: Take a look at ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github

Comment: Take a look at https://builditmasters.com/git-config-username-and-password-global/  too

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Make sure you are using the SSH URL for the GitHub repository rather than the HTTPS URL. It will ask for username and password when you are using HTTPS and not SSH. You can check the file `.git/config` or run `git config -e` or `git remote show origin` to verify the URL and change it if needed.

You can change the URL with: <sup>[1]</sup>

```
git remote set-url origin git+ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git
```

<sub>[1] This portion incorporates the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/how-do-i-avoid-the-specification-of-the-username-and-password-at-every-git-push).</sub>

Comment: I cannot use SSH because of internal firewall rules (don't ask...) Is there another way to let git login automatically?

Comment: @Jorn not being able to change the ports used for SSH is a right pain in the bum.

Comment: Is the git+ssh:// useful? I tried and got an error but removing it and then pushing it worked.

Comment: Finally something that works !

Answer (score 111):

From Git Bash I prefer to run the command:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

At that point running a command like `git pull` and entering your credentials one time should have it stored for future use. Git has a built-in credentials system that works in different OS environments. You can get more details here: *[7.14 Git Tools - Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage)*

Comment: Is there a linux alternative, or does this work for linux too ?

Comment: git config --global credential.helper cache https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-password-in-git

Comment: @SoldOut you know where the term "bash" in "git bash" stems from, right?

Comment: @clockw0rk Oh, yes sure - thank you for the good hint. I just... that git versions do differ quite substantialy even on same OS, so I thought here might be difference for UX derivate systems too.

Comment: what does `wincred` do?

Comment: Assuming git is configured to use Windows Credential Manager, any future password changes can be done by GUI or my preference is command line.  `cmdkey /list git*` list the git credentials. `cmdkey /add target-from-list /pass:NewPassword`

Answer (score 97):

For those who are using access token and a Windows environment, there is a simple way to do it:

Start menu → *Credential Manager* → *Windows Credentials* → find the line (Git: https://whatever/your-repository/url) → edit,
*user name* is "github_username" and *password* is your access token.

Comment: I have multiple git accounts for diff companies I work with, I guess there isn't a way to store more than one in the credential manager?

Comment: user name is "github username"

Comment: This was usefull to setup the value to use, but to tell git to use this manager follow @IcedDante or @notreadbyhumans answer: `git config --global credential.helper wincred`

Answer (score 22):

If you are a Mac user and have keychain enabled, you to need to remove the authorization information that is stored in the keychain:

```
- Open up Keychain access
- Click "All items" under category in the left-hand column
- Search for git
- Delete all git entries.
```

Then you should change your username and email from the terminal using `git config`:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Bob"

$ git config --global user.email "bob@example.com"
```

Now if you try to push to the repository you will be asked for a username and password. Enter the login credentials you are trying to switch to. This problem normally pops up if you signed into GitHub on a browser using a different username and password or previously switched accounts on your terminal.

Comment: This helped me. Although, there is no need to delete the git entries, you can edit them right there.

Answer (score 17):

I wrote an answer in this other answer: [How to change git account in Git bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689395/how-to-change-git-account-in-git-bash/64627127#64627127)

Still, I am sharing it here as well.

**Change username and email global**

```
git config --global user.name "<username>"
git config --global user.email "<email>"
```

**Change username and email for current repo**

```
git config  user.name "<username>" --replace-all
git config  user.email "<email>" --replace-all
```

Answer (score 12):

With git bash for Windows, the following combination of the other answers worked for me (repository checked out using the GitHub client i.e. https, not ssh):

1. [Generate a Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)
2. Start a git bash session within your repo
3. run `git config --global credential.helper wincred`
4. run `git pull`
5. give PersonalAccessToken as the username
6. give the Personal Access Token as the password

Answer (score 6):

add remote as:

```
git remote add https://username:password@github.com/repodir/myrepo.git
```

Comment: It is now git remote add <name> <url>

Comment: @LoganGeorge What is <name> exactly?

Comment: @A__ the name you want to set for the remote, eg origin

Answer (score 4):

First Store username name password globally, By using this command

```
git config --global github.user <your_username>
```

then use this command

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Answer (score 3):

If the git bash is not working properly due to recently changed password.

> You could open the Git GUI, and clone from there.   It will ask for
> password, once entered, you can close the GIT GUI window.

Now the git bash will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try ssh-agent for installing the SSH key for use with Git. It should auto login after use of a passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

GnuPG can be used as cross-platform password manager, including GIT HTTPS credetials.
Just use your GPG key-pair to encrypt/decrypt passwords(tokens...).
To encrypt token(password) run:

```
gpg -e -o [PATH_TO_ENCRYPTED_TOKEN] -r "[GPG_KEY_USER_ID]"
```

type the token (or copy-paste it) then press Ctrl+D for ending input, or use file name with this token.
Then make custom git credential helper: BASH file with name git-credential-[HELPER_LAST_NAME] (without SH extension):

```
#!/bin/bash
token=`gpg -d -r "[GPG_KEY_USER_ID]" [PATH_TO_ENCRYPTED_TOKEN] 2>/dev/null`
echo protocol=https
echo host=[YOUR_HOST]
echo username=[YOUR_USER_NAME]
echo password=$token
```

On MS-WINDOWS in GIT-BASH path names must use UNIX file separator - "/", just run in git-bash "echo $PATH"!
Then put the helper into place as in $PATH.
Then add and check the helper:

```
git config --global credential.helper [HELPER_LAST_NAME]
#then check it (password will be printed as plain text!!!):
git credential-[HELPER_LAST_NAME]
```

GnuPG can be used as password manager in Maven projects instead of Maven's password-encryption method.
And so on.

Answer (score 0):

If your repo is of HTTPS repo, git config -e give this command in the git bash.
Update the username and password by opening in insert mode, change the password or username give :x and Cntrl+z keys 
it will save and exit

So, From then  while you pull / push the code to the repository it will not ask for password.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple Solution, you have to use quotations:

```
git config --global user.name "your name"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not tried this option. It solves the issue of configuring username and password on Git Bash. Namely, being able to git push to your repo.

```
$ git init
$ git config user.name "yourusername"
$ git config user.email "youremail@email.com"
$ git add *
$ git commit -m "msg to be committed"
$ git push origin master/main
```