# bash script adding git credentials from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to be able to add git credentials from my to my bash script but can't figure out how to do this.

```
git clone https://xxxxxxx
```

would ask for my username name and password.

how to i pass these in a bash script ?

any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68602613/1803897) contains a sample bash script.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For basic HTTP authentication you can:

1. Pass credentials inside url:

   ```
   git clone http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@some_git_server.com/project.git
   ```

   **WARN** this is not secure: url with credentials can be seen by another user on your machine with `ps` or `top` utilities when you work with remote repo.
2. Use [gitcredentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials):

   ```
   $ git config --global credential.helper store
   $ git clone http://some_git_server.com/project.git

   Username for 'http://some_git_server.com': <USERNAME>
   Password for 'https://USERNAME@some_git_server.com': <PASSWORD>
   ```
3. Use `~/.netrc`:

   ```
   cat >>~/.netrc <<EOF
   machine some_git_server.com
          login <USERNAME>
          password <PASSWORD>
   EOF
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can still pass in the username and password into the URL for `git clone`:

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

As for using a bash script, You can pass the username `$1` and password `$2`:

```
git clone https://$1:$2@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Then call the script with:

```
./script.sh username password
```

Addtionally, It might be more secure to leave the password out and only include the username:

```
git clone https://$1@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Since the command with your password will be logged in your bash history. However, you can avoid this by adding a space in front of the command.

You can also use [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash) for nicer ways to use command line arguments.

Also be careful to use [URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for special characters in usernames and passwords. A good example of this is using `%20` instead of `@`, since URLS need to use standard ASCII encoding for characters outside the standard character set.

Answer (score 2):

1) This may help you [add credentials git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840551/configuring-user-and-password-with-git-bash)

2) I currently work with gitlab and I have it in a container with jenkins, anyway to do the clone I do this: `http://<user_gitlab>@ip_gitlab_server/example.git`

I hope I help you