# Failing pulling existing Repo in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, github, repository, pull-request

I downloaded a branch as zip file from git succesfully. After this I cloned repo from in the section below. But still I cant see all the branches that I wanna see. What's the problem here?

[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDcns.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using,

`git clone {repo-URL}`

In this way the cloned directory will be a git repository with all the git history and branches...

Comment: After this it wanted my username in github and password but it doesnt let me type my password. whats the problem

Comment: you need to login in to your git bash with your credentials, otherwise, you may `git init` that directory to add its origin via `git remote add origin {repo URL}` but still you have to be signed in for that...
without signing in you may not get the history as of what I know...
I suggest to have a look on htis one for your login https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840551/configuring-user-and-password-with-git-bash

Comment: Accept the answer as an accepted answer... @mertckr and upvote too. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You may either use git bash,

```
git clone {repo-url}
```

if the GitHub account is not configured,

```
git config --global user.name {your-GitHub-username}
git config --global user.email {your-email}
```

In case you donot want to use git bash or terminal for that, try using `GitHub Desktop` [Download](https://desktop.github.com/) so everything will be in GUI and much more easy than bash.