# input inside script with Subprocess.call()

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, subprocess

If I run `git push origin master`, it asks for my Github username and password. How would I put these in with call() like this `call(['git', 'push', 'origin', 'master'])`? When I look at the git-push man page, it says nothing about these being arguments.

Comment: They aren't. You're likely going to have to use `Popen` and the `PIPE` inputs to stdin/stdout, but I'm not sure if the exact method so I'll leave it to someone else to answer.

Comment: you could [use ssh keys to avoid entering the password every time](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).

Comment: @aruisdante: It is likely that the password is read from the terminal directly i.e., `PIPE` won't work. See [Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push : username , password, how to avoid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/git-push-username-password-how-to-avoid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the protocol of my repo to ssh from https. This removes the need to enter a password