# git push in the background python tkinter

Tags: python, git, tkinter

i am building a simple python gui app using tkinter which will utilize this command in the background:

```
os.system( 'git push bitbucket master' )
```

as this command will be executed in the background, there is some issue that i am facing like while providing the password for the git account to push into the git server.

how to automatically provide the git user password when it is prompted in the background or include the password inline like:

```
os.system( 'git push bitbucket master -p=mypassword' )
```

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/git-push-username-password-how-to-avoid

Comment: thanks, it would helpful if this could be managed via the app

Comment: As an aside, you might want to look at using Python's subprocess module's call() or popen() to run commands, esp if you want to look at the stdout/stderr for some reason. You can also avoid this whole subprocess mess by using the gitpython module directly.