# Git push: how to avoid username and password in multiple repository?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I refer to [Git push: username, password, how to avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/git-push-username-password-how-to-avoid) set my ssh key, it works.

But now, i clone **another repository** into my computer, once again i refer to that guide, copy the contents of my ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub into the Deploy keys of this repository, github tell me 'Key is already in use'.

How can i avoid username and password in both two repository?

Comment: I don't think you need to do this again and again.

Comment: my first repository don't need password, but my second need. What can i do such that don't need password?

Comment: You should clone the repository via `ssh` instead of `https`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you're cloning repos for your own use (not deploying to server etc.) you should add your SSH key to your GitHub profile via https://github.com/settings/keys . Then there is no need to add separate keys for each repository.

Then, clone repository using SSH URL (not HTTPS). For example, if your repository is at `https://github.com/youruser/yourrepo` do `git clone git@github.com:youruser/yourrepo.git`.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have added the ssh key(id_rsa.pub) of your local machine to Github. Then you should always clone the respository using `ssh` instead of `https`.

```
git clone https://github.com/user_name/repo
git clone git clone git@github.com:user_name/repo.git
```

Always avoid first if you have added the `ssh` key.