# How do I suppress the repository url when pushing or pulling with git?

Tags: git

I have a repository that has a remote to azure-devops.

I have to go through a proxy if that matters, but that's setup and working correctly. I don't think this will be an issue for this question.

You can add a token to the remote url (in the form of https://user:pat@dev.azure.com/...), which I do because copy-n-pasting the pat every single time is annoying.

When pushing or pulling, the full url is displayed.

```
$ git push azure dev
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 279 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Analyzing objects... (2/2) (163 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (177 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (31 ms)
To https://user:mypat@dev.azure.com/user/path/to/repo <<<---
   b20e4fd..b1772a1  dev -> dev
```

How can I suppress the 'To https...' line?

**Edit**: This is not a duplicate, because that answer changes authentication protocol to ssh keys. Because I have to use a proxy (see second paragraph) I can't use ssh keys.

Comment: What do you mean by suppress? As I’m not letting it be output by git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I avoid the specification of the username and password at every git push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588768/how-do-i-avoid-the-specification-of-the-username-and-password-at-every-git-push)

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help as well: https://serverfault.com/a/912788

Comment: @ochi The OP doesn't ask how to get username/password. The question is about how to hide username/password from public logs.

Comment: @phd never said anything to the contrary.   First link indicates that, if using an SSH key, you don't need to enter user/pass credentials (and, thus, avoid showing them on logs) - the other link illustrates how to to use a shell that echos env variables (which contain user/pass) - The poster of this one indicated it does not echo values to screen either.

Comment: @ochi I think such links require more explanation than just links. This one is better than nothing, thanks.

Comment: You can't. You need to use a solution which doesn't put credentials in the URL, either by using a credential helper of some sort or by using SSH.

Comment: @phd the explanations are in the answers themselves.  OP can read them as well as any other user - I do not see the need to spoon-feeding or duplicating a well-explained answer (diluted into a comment).  Do you?

Comment: Edited to explain why I think this isn't a duplicate. @ochi pointed me in the right direction, however, with his second link. I'm creating an answer for this question now.

Answer (score 1):

@ochi pointed to a comment on another, similar question. The [following comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/815043/how-to-give-username-password-to-git-clone-in-a-script-but-not-store-credential/815055#815055) held my answer.

Using `.netrc` to hold my authentication information works as desired. Make sure to `chmod 0600 ~/.netrc` or it won't work.

```
machine dev.azure.com
login user
password personalaccesstoken
```

This is the output I'm getting now.

```
$ git push azure test
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 289 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 2 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Analyzing objects... (2/2) (126 ms)
remote: Storing packfile... done (244 ms)
remote: Storing index... done (95 ms)
To https://dev.azure.com/user/path/to/repo <<<---
   24a77ad..5ee5fcb  HEAD -> test
```

**Updated**

As pointed out in the comments, this is not a perfect solution. The `.netrc` file is used by other applications and this information will be available to them. This works in my situation, you should evaluate yours and decide if this is what you want.

Comment: Beware that this solution leaves your user/pass in the `~/.netrc` file - which other systems might be able to read or have access to.  This is undesirable in some cases.

Comment: Edited to incorporate your warning. Thank you.