# SSHing git@github.com shows wrong/old SSH key

Tags: git, ssh, github, ssh-keys

k, so I was setting up [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and followed [this tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) to set up an SSH key. The fingerprint was `16:27:...:a6:48`. I installed the [GitHub client for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) which set up a new SSH key automatically called `github_rsa` in the `%user%/.ssh/` folder.

I deleted the "old" SSH key (don't ask me why) and set up a new one with the fingerprint `a6:17:ed:4a:1d:9a:c7:63:6a:a1:38:8b:96:e3:91:bf` I had simply deleted the previous `id_rsa` keys and the `known_hosts` file and then used `ssh-keygen` to make another - I didn't mess with the GitHub key).

Now, whenever I try to ssh into `git@github`, it says:

> The authentication of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be estabilished
>   RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:...:a6:48
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

which is NOT what I want. It's showing the old SSH key which I'd deleted (along with `known_hosts`). What do I do?

**[Edit]:** I was (wrongly) assuming that the fingerprint from the output of the terminal would match the fingerprint of *my* Public RSA key. I still have an issue with the SSH, but it's not related to this (the question has already been asked, read: [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)). I'd delete this question, but it doesn't allow me to, saying "It has 1 or more answers. Please flag it for moderator attention." _even though its mine. Read more at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140646/what-should-i-do-if-i-realize-the-premise-of-a-question-was-faulty-but-i-alread/140676#140676

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you should edit your `<USER>/.ssh/config` file (or create it) with

```
Host github.com
User <USER>
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa

Host *
User <USER>
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and that would do the trick if what happens is what you're saying.

But maybe it is not a problem, as *Step 5: Test everything out* of your link says that you may see this warning:

```
# The authenticity of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established.
# RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
# Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

and you shouldn't worry, this is supposed to happen. Just verify that the fingerprint matches the one here and type "yes".

Answer (score 1):

Since you deleted your known_hosts file, ssh-agent will give this warning:

> The authentication of host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be
>   estabilished RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:...:a6:48 Are you sure you
>   want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

the first time it tries to connect to this host as well as any other hosts you SSH into. For every new host you say 'yes', the host's fingerprint gets added into the **known_hosts** file.

If you DO get the warning every time, then you have a bigger issue that your known_hosts file is not being written by ssh or read back. You can verify if you're given this warning message each time you SSH into some other machine as well.

[Further reading](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/unix/sshknownhosts.html)