# IntelliJ IDEA GitHub integration creates the repository, but gets "couldn't authorize" error trying to push

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

1. I create a new project in IntelliJ IDEA
2. Via the menu, I go to VCS -> Import into Version Control -> Share project on GitHub
3. Enter a new repository name and click Share
4. It authenticates with GitHub ok
5. When I try to push to GitHub, a login window opens that says "Login to https://github.com/myemail@gmail.com/GitHubTest2.git"
6. The default login is github.com/my_username. I try to login with that login and my GitHub.com password and authentication fails. I also try to login with my GitHub.com login (i.e. myemail@gmail.com) and my GitHub.com password.
7. After 3 tries, I get the following error message:

Push to GitHub failed
Push authorization failure: 
Couldn't authorize

Why does it authenticate with GitHub with my GitHub.com login/password but not when it tries to push the project to GitHub?

Comment: Try now. Github had a massive service interruption today and only recently has restored services.

Comment: I saw that, but it's not the issue. I was having this problem before and still have it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. See [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password) .
2. Try to use ssh instead of https ( with the generated keypair:
   https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys ).

This may solve the issue for you, for me it just changed the error message I was seeing in IntelliJ from GitHub to "remote host hung up unexpectedly."

I then tried pushing to GitHub from terminal and it worked. From terminal, it works regardless of whether I use SSH or https. I therefore suggest using command line git for pushing code to GitHub instead of the IntelliJ integration.

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me:

- Instead of using username and password use a personal access token. In GitHub: Go to "Account settings" > "Applications" and generate a "Personal Access Token"

In IntelliJ:

- Go to "Settings" > "Version control" > "GitHub" and enter your login and the generated access token. Now pushing to the GitHub repo should work.

Comment: Didn't work with IU 129.713. I'm using ssh access. Intellij confirms that my credential (name, access token) works. Did I need to checkout the github repo using https? git push on command line (bash, ubuntu) works.

Comment: Pilot error on my part. Setting the IDE to use the native ssh allows it to work.

Comment: using the token was the only way I could get this to work!