# can I store password somewhere using git via http(not https)

Tags: git

I'm using a proxy(developed on GAE) which can only work using http.
So when i try to `git push` I have to input password and user-name every time.

Can I store it somewhere and don't bother to input it any more?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password

Comment: [password chching](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#password-caching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for http, but you could try adding a netrc entry. In your home directory create a file called `_netrc` (or `.netrc` if on a nix box) if it doesn't exist. Then add an entry of the following format:

`machine github.com login [your login] password [your password]`

This assumes github, of course. Change the site as needed.

**EDIT**

Just to be clear... you *are* storing your password in plain text on your machine going this route. Though given your restrictions you might be stuck.

Comment: awesome! It worked perfectly.I also want to know about it's safety.

Comment: Well... you're storing a password in plain text on your hard drive... so it's as safe as the machine you're using.