# Git Always Prompts for Passphrase

Tags: macos, git, github, ssh

I've followed the following guide to setup SSH keys on Mac OS 10.7.4.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

But for some reason it continually prompts me for my passphrase. It doesn't prompt me if I don't specify a passphrase, but that isn't desired. Is there a way to cache my passphrase so that I won't be prompted for every pull/push?

Comment: Where is it that you dont want to be prompted for a passphrase? When generating an ssh key?

Comment: Has this been resolved? Did you follow the instructions at [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-mac) exactly? See also [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6565357/456814).

Answer (score 8):

You have to add your key file in the ssh-add

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/you_key_rsa
```

After that, it's not will ask any more.

Comment: @Phillip, you should mark one of the answers as correct or provide your own solution.

Comment: I started getting these prompts on macOS after upgrading to Ventura and this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to edit the `.git/config` file in your git repo and change the `url` value to use something like `user@host:path-to-git-repo.git`

Answer (score 0):

The SSH password is used to authenticate users connecting to GIT repositories.
If you're working localy, git shouldn't ask for passwords, obly when doing remote operation, such as clone, push, pull,etc.

If the password annoys you, you can just input a blank password when creating the SSH key, password is not mandatory, however I advise you to use password for extra protection.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10, and I have found two ways to eliminate the passphrase prompting.

1. Make sure the ssh agent is started and you have added your key

   ```
   $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

   $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

The second command will prompt you for your passphrase, and then you will not be prompted for any other git commands run in this session.
You will need to run these commands again for every new bash session

2. Remove the passphrase from you key file:

   ```
    $ ssh-keygen -p -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

When prompted, just strike enter key for the new passphrase.

Option 2 will permanently remove the passphrase for all git commands.   Of course it also makes you key file "unsecured"

Note:  If you are using git desktop GUI ( Version 1.04+)  Option 2 is required for the GUI to work.