# Github sign in before a push

Tags: github

When I try to push my project on Github, I have to sign in every time with my Github account before the push. And I don't understand why, on certain projects I don't need to do this, only on one project.

```
MacBook-Pro-Firstname:ProjectName firstname$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': email@gmail.com
Password for 'https://email@gmail.com@gmail.com@github.com': *******
```

How can I remove the sign in process?

Comment: You probably cloned them via HTTPS instead of SSH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub offers two different authentication methods for read/write access. The first, which you appear to be using, is the HTTPS method and requires username/password authentication. The other way is via SSH which uses public/private key pairs to authenticate rather than a username/password combination.

To change the URL of the repository to the SSH version, you can use `git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:username/repository.git`

It sounds like you already have SSH keys generated and added to your account if you don't need to authenticate for some projects, but if you don't you can set it up via [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) link.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure but I believe you will need to create an SSH key: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a public SSH key with Github. See this article: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys