# Git Push: I can't add a file to my Repo since Git doesn't allow me to enter my Github password

Tags: git, git-push, github-for-windows

#### Intro

I'm pretty new to Git and Github, and I am just trying to add (new) files to a repo I created on Github. I have Windows 7. I have found some supposed solutions for Linus/OX on Stack Overflow, but it does not work for Windows 7.

I have found a similar question on Stack Overflow. Users answered that it is common for passwords to remain invisible, but that it should work if you enter in the password anyways.

#### Problem

I have committed various files and need to push them to GitHub from Git. In Git Bash/the terminal, all steps from the beginning tutorials/Google answers to add files from your computer onto GitHub are successful until the very last step (`git push origin master`).

At this point, the terminals prompt me to enter my username (no problem, successful) and my password. Nothing shows up when I type my password. If I type my password in and press enter afterwards anyways, nothing happens and it does not work. I have tried this multiple times. The password is correct as it works on GitHub, but it does not work on the terminal.

#### Further information

GitHub shows that I have a ReadMe file and a license in my repo. I will need to add an html, css, and jpg file to GitHub.

Comment: Please add the output of `git remote -v` to your question. Did you set up your remote to use https or ssh? If ssh, does your private key have a passphrase? **ALSO**, if you looked up other Stack Overflow questions, **PLEASE LINK TO THEM IN YOUR QUESTION**, so that we know what you have tried already, and so then nobody wastes time trying things that you've already tried.

Comment: In response to git remote -v I get: origin https://github.com/username/nameofrepo (fetch) and https://github.com/username/nameofrepo (push). I have no idea whether my remote is set to https or ssh, but certainly don't remember setting it or creating a passphrase.

Comment: Based on your `git remote -v` output, it looks like you're using https. Are you getting any error messages when you try to push? Also, you might want to consider using ssh instead of https, so that you don't have to enter your password every time you do a network operation like `push`, `pull`, or `fetch`. **ALSO**, ***what are the exact commands that you have been using to commit and push your code***? Have you made any commits to your local repo yet? Have you used `git add` and `git commit` before you tried `git push`?

Comment: Also, are you ***really sure*** that you ***entered your password correctly***? It can be hard to tell from the prompt since it doesn't display `*` characters (probably for security reasons).

Comment: Found [this answer for storing https passwords with GitHub for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password/15826989#15826989). But if you're using the command line anyways, why even bother using GitHub for Windows? If you want to become proficient in Git, you should learn to use it from the command line anyways.

Answer (score 1):

When you type the password the cursor won't move on the command-line. Then type the password, then press enter. I got it to work!