# Still requiring login after SSH authentication

Tags: github, ssh

I followed everything in the GitHub tutorial: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

I did all the commands in the directory of my repository.
I reached the end of tutorial successfully and got the message: "Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not # provide shell access."

However when I tried to do things such as push it still requested for my username and password.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer, but I never personally got Github to work directly via ssh. So what I did instead is just leave my SSH key there `git push git@github.com:name/repo` which authenticates via SSH. Perhaps you could give that a try. I couldn't tell you what I did, though, let's just say that.. it works and I don't want to break it.

Comment: I tried that, it gave me: "Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for <IP Address> to the list of known hosts."

However, it still requires login -.-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)

Comment: Expanding on the above answer:
You can find your ssh link for the remote origin on your github repository page by clicking on the clone or download button and then clicking on the use SSH link on the top right of the dropdown.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Check your `remote`s via `git remote -v`.

`https://` URLs will always ask for a password, unless you configure a *credential helper*. More info on that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github).

The simplest solution for password-less git access would be to use the [`git remote set-url`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) command and set an **SSH** url for the existing repo.

In your case, `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:name/repo`.

Then you should be able to `git push origin <branch>` without being asked for a password.

Comment: You missed `.git` in end of `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:name/repo.git`

Comment: I wish I saw your answer before I wasted 2 hours on this. Thank you very much!

Comment: In reference to github's own article: https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password/

Comment: `.git` at the end of the URL is not needed. It'll work without it too.

Answer (score 19):

Good that you have correctly setup your git ssh now you need to reclone the git repository with ssh for example previously you would have done something like this :

```
git clone https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker.git
```

this was a https clone now you need to clone with ssh as

```
git clone git@github.com:dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker.git
```

you can find the ssh link from your github account same place where you found your https link.
After this you can easily push without your password prompt .

It might though ask for your ssh unlock password. You then need to enter the paraphase you gave during the creation of your ssh key . If you left it blank it might not prompt for it .

Comment: fatal: destination path <repository> already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: you need to clone it in some other directory or delete the current git directory .

Comment: @kaushikgandhi OP don't necessarily need to re-clone or delete, see my answer

Comment: @user2062950 correct your answer is perfect . You can simply change the remote origin that would serve the purpose

Answer (score 3):

I was able to stop the username & password prompt by opening `.git/config` from the base repo directory and changing the remote URL.

For example:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/username/my-repo.git
```

should be changed to:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:username/my-repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer marked as correct but couldn't make it work. This worked for me instead `git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame`