# access to bitbucket.org via ssh on linux

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm trying to connect to bitbucket.org via the command line without a request for a password.    I know there have been plenty of posts about this but my question is I think a bit more basic.

I'm running git version 2.7.4 on Ubuntu linux in case that matters.

I've added a public key seemingly correctly, and all my permissions on .ssh are 700.     I suspect the problem is that in .git/config, I had

```
[remote "kss1"]
    url = https://bitbucket.org/<myName>/kss1
```

which several posts have identified as a problem.     Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797940/still-requiring-login-after-ssh-authentication) I've modified the url line to

```
[remote "kss1"]
url = git@bitbucket.org:<myName>/kss1
```

And the response is now

```
repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

.Googling this error didn't yield anything terribly helpful.

Could anybody advise please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what key exactly is used with:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -v' git push
```

From there, make sure your public key (used by ssh in the previous command) has been copied to your profile (SSH settings) as *one* line.

Make sure you don't have multiple remotes (type `git remote -v`) and that you are indeed using `git push kss1` (by default, `git push` pushes to `origin`)

---

Regarding the public key copy issue, the [OP Leo Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1344098/leo-simon) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547326/access-to-bitbucket-org-via-ssh-on-linux/50547413#comment88108302_50547413):

> I guess there was a space somehow in the copy of the public key.
>   I remade the public key and now it's working.
>   No more password prompts!

Comment: Thanks very much, I guess there was a space somehow in the copy of the public key.    I remade the public key and now it's working.    No more password prompts!