# How do I stop GitX asking me for my SSH key password?

Tags: gitx

In order to let myself log into two different Heroku accounts I'm using `.git/config`

```
[core]
  repositoryformatversion = 0
  filemode = true
  bare = false
  logallrefupdates = true
  ignorecase = true
[branch "master"]
[remote "heroku"]
  url = git@myrepo:myrepo.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:peternixey/myrepo.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

and `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myrepo
  HostName heroku.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myrepo
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

#### GitX doesn't seem to be able to handle this

[image]

GitX doesn't seem to be picking up the correct key for the account. It keeps trying to use id_rsa.pub when the correct key is myrepo.pub. There is also a passphrase on the RSA key itself.

This is GitX(l) (as in L for Lima) and it's  basically unusable in the current configuration, how can I stop the password demands?

Comment: This can also happen when you [clone the `https://` URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565661/265521) instead of the `git://` one. Apparently you can't use key authentication via HTTPS for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by deleting the previous keys and regenerating them. I think that somehow GitX had got caught up with the wrong key (or else I was entering the wrong password). Seemed more likely to be my fault than GitX's

Comment: hi, how did you delete/regen your keys? At command-prompt? -thx