# Windows git bash interactive is not working?

Tags: git, user-interface

I have download gitbash clone a repository through the command line and worked fine, when I am trying to push I am getting a :

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such file or directory.
```

If I use the git ui to push it's asking me for a username and password and it's actually works.

Comment: i've been seeing this too trying to set up some co-workers machines..  It appears to be only Windows platform specific.. it must be a bug with git for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the result of a very serious [bug in Git for Windows 1.8.5.2-preview20131230](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/153).

Downgrading to [Git for Windows 1.8.4](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?q=full%20installer%20official%20git) should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you clone from your fork of the repository or did you clone directly from a repository? If its the latter then you may not be able to push your changes. Instead try [sending a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests#initiating-the-pull-request).

Also see this related question: [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)