# Cannot delete Git's remote branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I set up a ssh key on the machine, cloned a branch on my local machine then tried to delete its associated branch on the remote. Below are my step.

1. Delete the local branch using `git branch -D abc-123`
2. Set the url to be ssh one. (`git remote set-url origin git@git_server:group_name/product_name.git`) [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)
3. Delete the remote branch using `git push origin --delete abc-123` [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely/2003515#2003515)

The problem is on step 3. it prompts for password and after I typed the correct one it say permission denied.

I wonder what I did wrong and how  to fix it.

Comment: Have you inform the remote server of your ssh public key ?

The good thing with ssh protocol is that you don't need to have a password (and it's fast). So unless the password is in fact your ssh pass phrase, there is something wrong.

Comment: @chaiyachaiya Yes, generated an ssh key and added it to My SSH Kay Page.

Comment: ok but when you say the "correct password", in what sense is it correct ? I mean normally, you do not have to give a password at all with ssh.
What happen if you do any remote opertation like "git remote show [remote_name]" ?

Answer (score 0):

To check what git uses under the hood run,

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin --delete abc-123
...
trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@github.com' 'git-receive-pack '\''group_name/product_name.git'\'''
...
```

Note the ssh commands that git runs.

Then follow GitHub’s troubleshooting [Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) and explicitly troubleshoot the ssh connection part for `ssh –vvT git@github.com`.