# git push asks for username and password when pushed to shared private repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

If Some one has shared his private repository to me than whenever I tries to push on that private repository it always asks me for username and password. But I have already added my private key in `ssh-keys` on my personal repository using [How To Add SSH Key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)

Now I can manage to push on my personal repository but not on other's private repository shared to me using ssh private key. Why? Is there a way to push on private repository with out adding my private key to other user's ssh keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking for the *username* and password means that you are using an https url for that repo.

```
https://username@github.com/anotherUsername/aGitRepoName.git
```

You should use the ssh url (`git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git`), which requires for your *public* key to be added to that private repo, making you a collaborator.
You would never need to add your private key anywhere, since it is... private.

See:

- "[Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)"
- "[Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)"