# Auto push to github without username and password

Tags: github, github-for-windows

after much messing around I have followed this tutorial on using a cmd prompt to push up to git hub

```
   http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2
```

However I have had to do a few things differently. Generating and adding the public key in GitHub went fine, however, adding the private key on my local machine has been a real pain.

I finally added it by opening a cmd prompt as administrator. then going to the directory where github was installed I then rand the following cmds to install the private key

```
bash
eval $(ssh-agent)
cd to-directory-where-private-.ssh-file-was-located
ssh-add .ssh
Identity added: .ssh (.ssh)
```

Prior to that I had numerous errors. However, when I run this from a batch file

```
cd c:/LocalDevelopment/PhoneGap/PfpMetrol
git init
git status


git add PhonegapData.js
git commit -m "Add PhonegapData.js"


git remote -v
git push
pause
```

it is still asking me for a username and password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)

Comment: Can you check the repo origin is not the https one you used to clone?

Comment: Could you post the output of `git remote -v`? In that way we can see if you are using the default https url or the ssh url you actually need.