# How to use the same SSH key for different GitHub projects?

Tags: git, github, ssh

I generated an SSH key and I'm using it on my GitHub project, but when creating a new project, what do I have to do to use it on a new project? It is very annoying to have to keep typing the password for every push.

Comment: this post should help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password

Answer (score 2):

Add your SSH key to your account, so that any repository under that account can be checked out without a password.

See: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: THANK YOU! Finally the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add your SSH key on Deploy Key's at Settings of your Gihub project.[image: Deploy Key's]