# Git asks for username and password even though SSH keys is setup

Tags: git, github

On my mac Git asks me for username and password everytime i login although i followed the step by step instructions at https://help.github.com/enterprise/2.3/user/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

Comment: Possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is github asking me username/password although I setup SSH authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337566/why-is-github-asking-me-username-password-although-i-setup-ssh-authentication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to resolve this by following the steps at https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Used the following command as i was having it installed already:

git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain

And now it doesnt ask for login credentials.

Comment: Don't know why this was selected as a correct answer. It doesn't answer the question, which is about how to login with SSH keys, not with username / password.