# Skip typing username and password on git push/pull commands

Tags: git, command-line

Anyone know how to set it up so when I'm in the command line and when I  `push/pull` to/from a git repository I don't have to type in my username and password?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push requires username and password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `http/https` as your transfer protocol you will be asked for `username` & `password` every time.

Switch to ssh key and you will not be asked anymore.

The sample below is how to set the key for GitHub, but i will be same for most of the servers with a minor changes (GUI).

The process is still the same

- Generate ssh-key
- Add the key to the server
- Change the protocol to ssh (`git://`)

---

### ***`Here is how to set it up:`***

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key as you mentioned )
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content to the relevant section (ssh keys) under your central repository.

---

### ***`For more information about the transport protocols read this:`***

- [`Local-Protocol`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol)
- [`The-HTTP-Protocols`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-HTTP-Protocols)
- [`The-SSH-Protocol`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol)
- [`The-Git-Protocol`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol)

---

### ***`How to set up ssh key under your GitHub account?`***

- Login to GitHub account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (***`Settings`***)
  [image]
- Click on the `SSH keys and GPG Keys`
  [image]
- Click on the `New SSH key`
  [image]
- Paste your key and save

Now it should work

---

### ***`Note`***

After the first set up open terminal and run a `git fetch` so the key will be tested and added to your `known hosts` file.