# Cant create release with git flow in source tree

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow, sourcetree

I'm using gitflow to create a new release but in the final step when pushing to remote on gitlab I get this error message:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.local': Device not configured
```

Have no idea why, may it be related to some settings on gitlab?

Comment: Try changing the origin from https to ssh - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

- embed your username in the url

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://{username}@gitlab.local
  ```

And use a [credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/6309) to cache the password.

- or use ssh.

I like to configure those remote url changes dynamically with:

```
git config  url."https://{username}@gitlab.local/".insteadOf https://gitlab.local/
git config  url."ssh://git@gitlab.local/".insteadOf https://gitlab.local/
```

That way, you don't touch the original remote url, and modify it when you use it.