# Git DOES NOT require username and password. How can I change it to do so?

Tags: git, github, rstudio

It seems as though the [common scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6565357/4089351) is to be in a safe computer, and receive prompts for username and password when pushing branches to GitHub from RStudio.

I have the reverse problem. I don't remember how I set it up, but it is not asking for username and password, pushing committed branches automatically.

How can I reverse the settings so as to be prompted every time?

Comment: GitHub profile settings > SSH & GPG keys > Delete SSH key related to the PC you want to prompt for username and password.

Comment: @J.Titus I am there, but it reads, "There are no SSH keys with access to your account",  and "There are no GPG keys with access to your account."

Comment: What is the output of `git config --get credential.helper`?

Comment: If you get any output, then you have a credential helper defined, and that could be caching your credentials.

Comment: @ScottWeldon Do you know how to get rid of it?

Comment: Yes, posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If that gives you any output, then you have a credential helper defined, and it could be caching your credentials.

To disable the helper, do:

```
git config --unset credential.helper
```

Depending on where the helper was defined, you may need to also include one of `--system`, `--global`, or `--local`. E.g.:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: I am getting `manager` as the output for `git config credential.helper`, and `fatal: not in a git directory` for `git config --unset credential.helper`. Do you know what this means?

Comment: @Toni It's probably defined at the system or global level then. As mentioned in my answer, please try the `--unset` command with either of the `--system` or `--global` flags.

Comment: What would be the entire command, for example with `--system`?

Comment: @Toni: Updated my answer.