# Attempting push on git and receiving "could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled"

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I'm using Visual Studio, and the GitHub Extension. I am able to sign in, then clone my team's repository, and then pull changes successfully.

When it comes time to push my changes back to remote, I get a blank command prompt appear on the screen briefly, and then the following errors in the output window:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
>
> fatal: AggregateException encountered. One or more errors occurred.
>
> error: cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
>
> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

EDIT: pushing via the command line works, as does pushing via the GitHub desktop application, just not within this extension.

Any ideas why this might be happening? I can't see why it needs the Username given that I have signed into the extension.

Comment: Do you use a password extension?   It might be blocking the User Access Control.   You could also revise your remote url to include your username.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password

Comment: @TaylorAckley thanks, I thought I tried everything in the other questions but didn't see this one hiding away.  Adding the username to the remote url was the only thing that worked (I have no password extension or anything unusual like that).  If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I was able to solve this by getting a 'access token' credential (that works between Visual Studio and Azure-Devops) and re-booting the computer hosting Visual Studio.  I don't know if this is a general solution or not.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As per my comment.   You can include your username in the remote URL (similar to FTP).

Example without password (SSH):

`git remote set-url origin git@github.com/username/repo.git`

Example with password (https)

`https://name:password@github.com/username/repo.git`

Source: [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)

Updated 5/14/2018 to correct `github.org` to `github.com` in the original answer

Comment: Actually, git remote set-url origin https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git
 but thanks anyway. Save me from the sysadmin.

Comment: In addition, when putting your password into the repo url, you need to replace special characters with their corresponding URL encoded values, for example: myp@ssword --> myp%40ssword

Comment: @Morgs see the above comment from maximus.

Comment: Where would you set this in visual studio? It seems to spawn a new terminal which doesn't know about this setting.

Comment: @kev - my answer is accepted, but there are better (newer) answers.

Answer (score 11):

Check that Windows does not have a pending update. If it does, update and restart.

Comment: This was it for me. Updating Visual Studio was required before it would allow me to do a push.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

Deleting the file %localAppData%\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache and then re-trying your logon.

Answer (score 3):

In windows go to credentials manager and check if generic credentials list has the below 
entries

git:https://github.com

https://github.com

If these entries are not  present add these entries with username and password and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when syncing. Updating visual studio to the latest version did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

**Using Windows Credential manager**

[image: **Windows Credential manager**]

After seeting username, password in Windows Credential Manager, set git config to read from credential manager. Open gitbash, run command:
**git config --global --add credential.helper manager**

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to disconnect from all the existing connections in Visual Studio, remove them one-by-one and connect from scratch. Then immediatelly I was able to clone the repository again.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue after I have only TLS1.2 enabled on my PC. After enabling TLS 1.1, SSL.x the issue was resolved. For enabling and disabling I used IISCrypto software. Hope that helps the team and other users.

Answer (score 1):

**In my case the same issue coming on below scenario:**

We are under corporate network. So we have our own proxy. When we try cloning we cant able to download due to same error.

I added proxy url in our git config.

```
[http]
 proxy=http://YourNameHere:YourPasswordHere@proxy.aaa.com:6050/
 sslVerify = false

[https] 
proxy=http://YourNameHere:YourPasswordHere@proxy.aaa.com:6050/
 sslVerify = false
```

Issue disappears and i can do all git operations.

Comment: For other people reading this, be wary of sslVerify - false it poses a security risk and opens you to man-in-the-middle attacks. This might be a valid solution for Andi, but not for everyone so please be wary.

A more robust solution to corporate environments is adding the certificate of the proxy to the trusted root certificates (a separate discussion).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my Visual studio 2017 and restarted it.
Now it's working fine.[My updated Visual studio version:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WWAz.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: For me also restarting VS 2019 solved it.