# homebrew-fuse git repository is deprecated brew update falied

Tags: git, homebrew, fuse

OS: 10.14.2

```
brew list
ant         gdbm            imagemagick     libtool         pango           telnet
apr         gdk-pixbuf      isl         libunistring        pcre            testdisk
apr-util        gettext         jansson         libxml2         pcre2           tree
autoconf        git         jemalloc        libxslt         pgcli           unixodbc
autojump        glib            jpeg            little-cms2     pixman          watchman
automake        gmp         libde265        lsusb           pkg-config      webp
boost           gnutls          libev           mongodb@3.6     plotutils       wget
c-ares          gobject-introspection   libevent        mpfr            postgresql@9.4      wxmac
cairo           goenv           libffi          ncurses         pwgen           x265
emacs           graphite2       libheif         nettle          python          xz
erlang          graphviz        libidn2         nghttp2         python@2        yarn
erlang@20       harfbuzz        libmpc          nmap            qt          zlib
fontconfig      htop            libomp          node            rabbitmq
freetype        htop-osx        libpng          openexr         readline
fribidi         icu4c           libpq           openjpeg        redis
gcc         iftop           libtasn1        openssl         shared-mime-info
gd          ilmbase         libtiff         p11-kit         sqlite


$ brew update
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Error: Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-fuse failed!`enter code here`
```

I suspects `fuse` is the root cause of my problem. But when I check `homebrew-fuse` repository to [solve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42915793/attempting-push-on-git-and-receiving-could-not-read-username-for-https-githu) my issue.

I have tried reinstall the it again using [this](https://github.com/jacobsa/homebrew-fuse)

```
brew tap homebrew/fuse
Error: homebrew/fuse was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
```

**Question:**

What is the root cause of this?
`fuse` or `git` or others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is really no more `homebrew/fuse` repository, as reported by `brew tap`:

> Error: homebrew/fuse was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.

You have to untap this repository with:

```
brew untap homebrew/fuse
```