# Cloning into D:\.. error: cannot spawn C:\.., permission denied fatal [Github Desktop]

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

```
Cloning into D:\.. error: cannot spawn C:\.., permission denied fatal: could not read Username for https://github.com: terminal promprs disabled
```

Such error appears when I try to clone a remote repo from github desktop, what could be the cause of this error? my dual-disc partition

**NOTE:**
I have access to clone the remote repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried executing Github Desktop as administrator and solved it

If it didnt solve it:

- I would recomend also viewing if the .bat file path exists or even the file exists
- check the instalation path of github and git (be sure they arent in different partitions)
- delete and reinstall Github Desktop and all dependencies (folders from AppData and others)

Comment: I would not recommend executing anything (beside crital system services) as Administrator on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not the latest GitHub Desktop, update it first, then check what credential manager is currently set (as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60383826/6309))

With the latest Git for Windows, it should be:

```
git config credential.helper
# you should see
manager-core
```

Note: the `git-credential-manager-core.exe` executable is in `<C:\path\to\Git>\mingw64\libexec\git-core\`, so you might have to adjust your `%PATH%` to reference it.

Comment: What exactly should I put in the "network or internet address" part when adding the credential?

Comment: @AndrésQuirozValdovinos You should not put anything directly in the Windows Credential Manager (as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48000893/6309). The Git credential helper (manager-core) will do that for you when you will enter your login/password.