# GitHub contributing by username

Tags: git, github, terminal

Using Terminal I made a few commits being:

```
git push
Enter username: username
Enter password: password
```

When I do it like this, the commits don't add up to my contribution graph on GitHub (even tough they are in the repository). However, when I do:

```
git push
Enter username: email address
Enter password: password
```

they show up. Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this just how GitHub works?

I've already set up the git config --global user.email and git config --global username.

Comment: You should use GIT thru ssh and configure it appropriately to avoid typing any user and password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch if you mean the git config --global user.email and .name, i've already done them.

Comment: Read some [SSH tutorial](https://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux). You want to generate a key, use a public key, etc. You certainly don't want to type a user + password on every `git push`

Comment: Make sure you have set that email to the same email that github has on file, or it cant count your contribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is not the "authentication" part. github counts contributions based on the mails of the authors of the revisions. *You* could push stuff from 100 other developers on a project (because they are the authors) and *they* would get the contributions.

Comment: And sure.... you could set up ssh certificates so there's no need to provide username/password every time you fetch/push.... but it's not related to the contribution problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

You should read an [SSH tutorial](https://support.suso.com/supki/SSH_Tutorial_for_Linux) (so generate *once* your SSH keys) and set up some SSH key on github using https://github.com/settings/keys

You should not have to enter your user & password at every `git push` (or any `git` command involving remote access to the github servers)

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565661/841108). So use e.g. `git clone git@github.com:karinakozarova/Made2Make.git` to clone your `Made2Make` github repository on your local computer

Comment: I think the question was about counting contributions, not the authentication