# Why does Github always ask for login credentials when I am trying to pull from the android studio terminal?

Tags: android-studio, github

I am trying to pull from a github repository from the local terminal of android studio. But I am asked to enter my login credentials every time I make a pull request. I tried setting up SSH key too but it did not work. When I enter the login credentials on the login window, it says wrong password, but when I enter the same credentials on the terminal [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCtUA.png), it accepts it.

[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first portion of your question:

Run the command `git config credential-helper store`

This will store your github credentials on your hard drive, meaning that after you enter your credentials once you won't have to enter them again. Your credentials will be unencrypted though, so if you have reason to believe your computer might get infected by ransomware, you might wanna go with another method.

Sources:
[Git Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store)
[Another StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65395514/9519820)