# Pushing to Git takes 4 steps, can this be reduced?

Tags: git

Every time I want to update a repository, for which I'm the owner and only contributor, it takes four often very redundant steps:

```
git add .
git commit -m "filename.html"
git push origin master
```

followed by entering the username and password.

I already set it such that it remembers the username and password (following steps like these: [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password) and others), but I still have to log in every first push, and it also times out so that if I don't do it for several minutes, I have to log in again.

And I know that if no new files have been created then I can remove the `add` line and use `git commit -am "filename.html"` instead.  Still, it would be nice if git could just monitor the whole directory instead of needing to manually add every new file.

Is there any way to automate or eliminate some of this?

Comment: Yea, make a shell script that does all of those things, then call the script.

Comment: Those are not redundant steps... Each one should be deliberate. For instance, you do want to be careful about what you stage.

Comment: @jub0bs I have never needed to be careful and don't foresee the need in the next year.  So I'm just always thoughtlessly entering the same thing 20 times a day, it'd be nice to get this out of the way.

Comment: @Addem That's how sensitive stuff ends up in repositories. Not to mention the terrible commit message. But each to their own, I suppose...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I already set it such that it remembers the username and password

Use ssh instead and you will not need to use username/password

```
# Open Git Bash.
# Run ssh-keygen and follow the on-screen messages (or simply click Enter till it over)

$ ssh-keygen

# Copy the key file (the content of the public key) located in:

~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

And you can always use a single line command: (or write a script to save time)

```
git add . && git commit -m "filename.html" && git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

make a file called `gcp`

Inside put these lines

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
git add .
git commit -m "$1"
git push origin master
```

or on Windows call it `gcp.bat`

and put these lines

```
git add .
git commit -m "%1" || exit /b %errorlevel%
git push origin master
```

now put `gcp` in your path and type

```
gcp "commit msg"
```

to run the commands.

ps: Personally I wouldn't do this but here's some rope.