# How can git push to master without having my password?

Tags: git

I am working in a private repo, so it's just normal that it asks for my password (I read [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password)), but before I was working in a public repo; how could git push to `master` without having my password ? Does that means anyone can enter just my username and email and push to `master` in my public repo ?

Comment: There's not enough information here. How's the repository set up? How's it hosted? What account are you using? Does it use a password or an SSH key? Are you providing it? Did you authenticate (once) with HTTPS or SSH in your client?

Comment: Is it GitHub or other services?

Comment: Public can mean many things. If it's read-write public then yes anyone can just push to it even without your username and email but using their own. Usually you can control these things. E.g. in github it's only public for reading and you have to specify which users are allowed to push to your repo when hosted there

Comment: Sorry, it is a GitHub public repository, and now it's a GitHub private repository

Answer (score 0):

I hope this useful for you:

If your partner team change the user and email like your's and push it, it can makes problems cause it seem's like change by you. I found this information to prevent this: Signature in Git

https://docs.github.com/es/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/signing-commits

Cheers :)