# SSH key using Git

Tags: git, github, ssh, repository, push

I'm new to GitHub and, after having followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/RGOj5yH7evk), I'm trying to understand SSH keys.

I already created a key and added it to my account. For the moment I have no more than a few test repositories, which I clones locally.

Now, the problem is that, even if I do not set my `ssh-agent` (or I remove all the keys from GitHub) I can still update my repos and push to them.

The only thing I can't do with a verified key is cloning a repository using the SSH link (e.g. `git@github.com:username/repository.git`), but I can still clone and push to repositories using the https link (e.g. `https://github.com/username/repository.git`).

I initially [thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password) that cloning was allowed using the https but I could not push, but I can even push and it does not ask any usernames of passwords!

So, what's the purpose of SSH keys if anyone can still do the same things that I do with a verified key?
Does it have to do with privileges and permissions?

Comment: You do have to enter your GitHub password to push to a repository, don't you? As far as cloning is concerned, GitHub repositories are public.

Comment: Possibly the key is still cached if you don't need a password for pushing.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it doesn't ask me any passwords...

Comment: How can I uncache it to verify it?

Comment: The [way to remove credential from your credential manager](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager) is outlined in the Git FAQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I can still clone and push to repositories using the https link (e.g. https://github.com/username/repository.git).

When using HTTPS, you would not use any SSH key, only cached credentials (GitHub account username/password), that would be provided by the git credential helper (`git config credential.helper`)

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"|git credential-xxx erase
```

Replace xxx by the helper returned by `git config credential.helper`

Comment: So the reason why GitHub doesn't ask me any credentials could be the fact that the credential helped might already be configured?

Comment: @Prelli Only if you are using an HTTPS URL, yes.