# Can't commit to github using SVN with Two Factor Authentication Enabled

Tags: github, svn

So, I use SVN with Github. I enabled Two Factor Authentication on Github and then I tried to commit to a repository with `svn commit -m "xxxxx"`. I was confronted with the username/password stout:

```
Authentication realm: <https://github.com:443> GitHub
Username: xxxxx
Password for 'xxxxx': ******
```

After entering the password a couple of times, I get:

```
svn: E215004: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E215004: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed
svn: E200042: Additional errors:
svn: E120191: Error running context: The requested authentication type(s) are not supported
```

I tried entering in my tokencode to the password prompt. I've also tried removing the local repository and resourcing it. I can checkout the repository just fine, but I can't make commits through svn. There was no problem with svn without Two Factor Authentication. Is there any way around this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to create a personal access token and input that as the 'password': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password/62235647#62235647

Comment: Hello @AdilB as I mention in my post, I have tried using the personal access token as the 'password'. That does not allow me to authenticate over svn. It works fine authenticating on the github website, but not when I try to `svn checkout` a repository. Further, that question link refers to the git process, not the svn one (similar but, clearly, not similar enough). Thanks for trying but, unfortunately, that one doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please comment back once you've figured this one out!