# Redirect 'terminal' to 'stdin' when pushing using git

Tags: git, push, stdin

Is there any way to redirect *terminal* input to *stdin* when pushing as below?

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Then I can pass my username/password through stdin.

For example, in linux based systems, the `sudo` command always read the password from terminal but if you provide it with a `-S` flag then it will read the password from stdin.

I'm just curious if there is any similar flag in `git` command?

**NOTE:** My question is just about redirecting input of `git` command to stdin and I don't care about security or any other thing.

Comment: Can u please check this link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565357/git-push-requires-username-and-password
There is something similar to what u asking about .
but maybe needs more steps to do it not using a flag.

Comment: @AhmadAmer Ok, I think I should give a shot at SSH URL. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git generally doesn't do its own password-asking: it fobs that job off on other programs.

When using ssh (`git clone ssh://...` etc.), Git just runs ssh itself directly.  That leaves everything up to ssh.

When using http or https, Git uses the libcurl library and *credential helpers*.  You can tell Git which credential helper to use, so you could write one yourself that reads a password from standard input, and tell Git to use that one.  This would be rather insecure, but you could definitely do it.

For the rest, see [Git push requires username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6565357/1256452).