# What is this type of login as shown in image called?

Tags: authentication, router

I am writing code to login into router and grab some settings. My code,that I wrote for HTML login does not work with the router login.

I have included the image. What is it ? Can I have code in c#, python or C to login into it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). And yes, you can use whatever language you are comfortable with as long as you can specify custom HTTP headers for the request.

Answer (score 0):

As Jifri said, it's Basic access authentication. You can log into it by sending the username and password as part of the URL you request:

http://username:password@url.com

See discussion here too: [Username and password in https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980912/username-and-password-in-https-url)