# Security: Trying to automate a task that needs login

Tags: excel, vba, security

I have a web query file (.iqy) that looks like so:

```
WEB1https://insertFavoriteWebpage
Formatting=Rich Text
DisableRedirections=False
```

As it stands, Excel attempts to open this link within itself (using IE) and prompts me to login. This login part is what I am trying to automate.

(1) What are the security implications that I should be concerned about when changing the link to this:

https://foo:password@insertFavoriteWebpage?

Right now, Excel will not open this updated web query file -- it returns with a '1004' error: "Microsoft Office Excel could not open or read this query file. Either the file has been damaged or the file format is not valid". But, typing this same updated link into a browser works.

(2) Does anyone know why?

I also looked at this page: [Username and password in https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980912/username-and-password-in-https-url/4980956#4980956), which also gave some helpful information.

(3) Does the part that mentioned the vulnerability using curl affect my situation?