# Basic auth to acess geoserver in a shiny app

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, geoserver

I need to access a geoserver to get images (through wms service) which is protected by username and password (base auth) in a shiny APP. Currently, I use `https://username:password@server-url/wms` to access geoserver. However, these method allow show username and password in the requests.

I have tried to call `GET` function in httr package, but doesn't work for me

```
a <- GET(wms_url, authenticate(user, password))
```

How could I hide the username and password?

Comment: You almost certainly want to do this from the backend and pass the result via a `renderUI` call. No matter what you do, from the front-end they will always be visible (because you've given them to the client). Your method will hide the info though to anyone snooping the packet, so I wouldn't worry about setting the header directly, via the second method. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980912/username-and-password-in-https-url