# Where do I get the username-password parts of the url in php

Tags: php, url

In PHP, For the url
`http://usx:psx@fw.eg-03.local/pax-neo-sandbox/v1/e`
Where do I get the username `usx` and password `psx` parts?

Based on the url:
[Username and password in https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980912/username-and-password-in-https-url)
I couldn't find it in the headers.
My .htaccess also has the lines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

If this is a duplicate, please can you point me in the right direction. I was unable to find it on stackoverflow.

Also, I don't need a username and password solution. I just need to get all the url parts or a reason for why PHP (or server) drops this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you need to get these details in a PHP script? Basic Auth is handled directly by the webserver anyway.

Comment: [Look here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php#70864)

Comment: @ADyson - analyze the full information of the request received and log it.

Comment: But why would that involve logging the user's credentials? In fact logging that ought to be considered a security risk. I guess maybe knowing the username could be useful, but not the password.

Comment: Ultimately though, you might be better with a PHP based login system. Basic auth is just that...for basic cases.

Comment: @ADyson - This is not for an engineered solution. It is an os cli + web + api based interface developed using php and c#. I only need to know if what the user sent as a request (typed in the browser bar) is received within php. We know '# part' doesn't need to come.

Comment: @Pippo Looks like HTTP_AUTHORIZATION doesn't get set from the URL parts - it only gets set when credentials are typed in from Basic Auth

Comment: @BrianPinto you are right, I did some test and it seems that Authorization header is 'ignored' perhaps for security reason.
Anyway take a look to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests i realized that %{HTTP:Authorization} seems to be ignored from Apache, also sending it by another application using cURL with explicit headers. Perhaps for secuity reasons.

**BUT** in my php `$_SERVER` variable I can find user and password  under *'PHP_AUTH_USER'* and *'PHP_AUTH_PW'* keys.

Moreover, for basic auth, I was able to extract the user and password from headers using this istruction: `[$user, $password] = explode (':', base64_decode(str_replace('Basic ', '', getallheaders()['Authorization'])));`
(in real world a bit of error management is needed)

Comment: Thanks for this answer - Took me a while though, You must be able to see this in your server because it may be run as an 'Apache Module' but these server variables disappear when run as a CGI module (but it comes from the header and not the URL parts). Ultimately it seems that The standard of [URL parts](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) is not followed. Even the URL spec doesn't have a TLDR and nothing definitive. Looks like this needs a wait for web standards to evolve :(. I've ignored it in the design. I have upvoted your answer though