# git clone over https 401 error and not asking for username or password

Tags: git, ubuntu, https

I have a private git repository on Codaset. Normally when I try to clone it over HTTPS on my Windows machine, it asks me for my username and password. When I try to clone it on an Ubuntu server, it never asks me for a username or password and it fails with a 401 error. What do I need to do differently?

Here is what I am doing:

```
git clone https://codaset.com/username/project_name.git destination_folder_name.git
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got it to work using this format:

https://username:password@codaset.com/username/project_name.git destination_folder

However according to these 2 posts, using that method could be a security problem:

[Can a username and password be sent safely over HTTPS via URL parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830074/can-a-username-and-password-be-sent-safely-over-https-via-url-parameters)

[Username and password in https url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980912/username-and-password-in-https-url)

Answer (score 12):

To avoid having to enter a password at all (on Windows or Unix), you can:

- check that HOME is defined (on Windows, it isn't by default)
- setup a `_netrc` file with the following content:

```
    machine codaset.com
    login your_codaset_login
    password your_codaset_password
```

Note: `%HOME%\_netrc` on Windows, `$HOME/.netrc` on Unix

That way, when you are cloning your repo, instead of typing:

```
 git clone https://username@codaset.com/username/project_name.git destination_folder_name.git
```

, you can remove the initial username:

```
git clone https://codaset.com/username/project_name.git destination_folder_name.git
```

and you won't have to enter a password.

---

If you don't want to put your credentials (in particular your password) in **plain text** in an `.netrc` file, you can **encrypt that `netrc` file with `gpg`**: see "[Is there a way to skip password typing when using https:// github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309)"

Comment: @zhaozhi great. You even can encrypt that `.netrc` file if you don't want your password put in plain text in a file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
git clone https://username@codaset.com/username/project_name.git destination_folder_name.git
```

to make it prompt for password.

Comment: That did make it prompt me for a password, but then it still fails with error 502

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question but my issue was because git was outdated with version 1.7.1. Updating git solved it. Here's how: https://travis.media/how-to-upgrade-git-on-rhel7-and-centos7/