# Git error 401 while accessing it via hudson's git plugin

Tags: git, github, hudson, jenkins

I have hudson configured on my server and i am using code fetched from my git repository.
Actually , i had set up the environment correctly and all the builds via Hudson were successful but recently i changed my git password from github.com and now all the builds fail giving a 401 error , I know its due to password change . Can anyone tell me how to change the password in Hudson via the git plugin so that the authentication passes.
Here is the error I am getting

```
ERROR: Problem fetching from origin / origin - could be unavailable. Continuing anyway
ERROR:  (Underlying report) : Error performing command: /usr/bin/git fetch -t 
https://github.com/xxx/xxx +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Command "/usr/bin/git fetch -t https://github.com/xxx/xxx +refs/heads/*:refs

/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: error: The requested URL returned error: 401 

while accessing https://github.com/xxx/xxx/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

ERROR: Could not fetch from any repository
FATAL: Could not fetch from any repository
```

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the GitHub setup, it is mentioned:

> Some tools connect to GitHub without SSH. To use these tools properly you need to find and configure your API Token.

```
$ git config --global github.user username
$ git config --global github.token 0123456789yourf0123456789token
```

> *Note* **If you ever change your GitHub password, a new token will be created and will need to be updated**.

Even though your ssh authentications should be unchanged, make sure the global git config used by the Hudson user has some github settings updated.

---

After [90 minutes of discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4143/discussion-between-vonc-and-nikhil-sharma), it turned out that the other file that can be impacted by a password change is your **`.netrc` file**.
See "[git clone over https 401 error and not asking for username or password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796171/git-clone-over-https-401-error-and-not-asking-for-username-or-password/5799159#5799159)"

Comment: Could not get it to work , changed the global settings but the error message is still the same.

Comment: @NikhilSharma: the other setting to check is the `HOME` value of your Hudson user, in order to be sure there is `HOME/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` files in it.

Comment: I tried to copy the public key to the github ssh keys but still could not get it to work. It still gives me the same error as above.

Comment: @NikhilSharma: you mean that before the password change, it was working even though your public ssh key *wasn't* on your GitHub account?

Comment: Yes. Strangely it was working without my ssh public key on the github account.

Comment: Yes. Strangely it was working without my ssh public key on the github account.

Comment: @NikhilSharma: that is a clear indication you were using your github token instead of ssh keys. Double check the user account used by Hudson is able to access the config `github.user` and `github.token` setting (and that you have updated the token appropriately).

Comment: I had tried the github.user and github.token but it didn't seem to work either , thats why i thought of configuring ssh . Can you please elaborate the process a little , it seems that I am missing something.

Comment: Where should I update github.user and github.token.Please help.

Comment: @NikhilSharma as mentioned in http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/, it is done in the git *global* config, which is a the `.gitconfig` file in your `HOME`. The all question is: where is `HOME` when used by the account used by Hudson?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4143/discussion-between-vonc-and-nikhil-sharma)

Comment: My hudson home is /var/lib/hudson and I checked the token and username values that are correct. When I try to manually fetch with git fetch origin master with root login. It works but when I logged in as hudson user it says permission denied. Any clues?When hudson fetches from the repository, who is the user?

Comment: Thank You very much VonC. Appreciate your help.