# msysgit is giving errors in Windows 7 32bit computer

Tags: git, msysgit, tortoisegit

I'm trying to clone code from the git server. I'm using windows 7, 32bit computer. I installed  [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=Git-1.7.8-preview20111206.exe&can=2&q=) and [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/downloads/detail?name=TortoiseGit-1.7.6.0-32bit.msi&can=2&q=).

But whenever I tried the clone command, I'm getting the following error:

```
git.exe clone   --progress -v  "http://vcs.hiit.fi/git/hiit_wfa" "C:\Users\athukora\Desktop\HIIT wide focus area\hiit_wfa"

Cloning into 'C:\Users\athukora\Desktop\HIIT wide focus area\hiit_wfa'...
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 (curl_result = 22, http_code = 401, sha1 = 9b1b551b5e4b7c7666df38c129d1ecc480c77347)
error: Unable to find 9b1b551b5e4b7c7666df38c129d1ecc480c77347 under http://vcs.hiit.fi/git/hiit_wfa
Cannot obtain needed object 9b1b551b5e4b7c7666df38c129d1ecc480c77347
while processing commit 876cb1098d91238e87c239b8151eeba5330f4480.
error: Fetch failed.
```

Can someone please help me to figure out the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're cloning a repository via HTTP protocol, and the server needs authentication (401 error is "Authentication required".

Provided you have credentials for the repoistory, you need to provide user name in URL:

```
git.exe clone   --progress -v  "http://usernname@vcs.hiit.fi/git/hiit_wfa" "<path>"
```

Git will then prompt you for password.

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5796171/11343) for other ways to provide your credentials.

Comment: Thank you. This is the command that worked for me https://username:password@vcs.hiit.fi/git/hiit_wfa destination_folder

Comment: it's preferable to not put `:password` there, as now your password is saved in your shell history

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes across the same problem in future please refer to this http://kumaripaba.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-use-git-in-windows.html

I made a detailed description of the problem I had and the solution.