# Phabricator git repository configuration issus on centos

Tags: git, http, centos, repository, phabricator

I am using cent os 6.6. I am trying to configure phabricate project management tool. I am facing issues while configuring git repository with http. Below is what i am trying to do and the error being thrown.

`git clone http://test.com/diffusion/SGLT/sg-local-test.git`

**Error**

> Initialized empty Git repository in /root/mani/sg-local-test/.git/
>   error: The requested URL returned error: 401 You must log in to access
>   repositories. while accessing
>   `http://test.com/diffusion/SGLT/sg-local-test.git/info/refs`
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: See answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5796171/1563512) on how to pass credentials using git over http.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you solved it ?